# Android "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Tags: android, multithreading

I've built a simple music player in Android. The view for each song contains a SeekBar, implemented like this:

```
public class Song extends Activity implements OnClickListener,Runnable {
    private SeekBar progress;
    private MediaPlayer mp;

    // ...

    private ServiceConnection onService = new ServiceConnection() {
          public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder rawBinder) {
              appService = ((MPService.LocalBinder)rawBinder).getService(); // service that handles the MediaPlayer
              progress.setVisibility(SeekBar.VISIBLE);
              progress.setProgress(0);
              mp = appService.getMP();
              appService.playSong(title);
              progress.setMax(mp.getDuration());
              new Thread(Song.this).start();
          }
          public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName classname) {
              appService = null;
          }
    };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.song);

        // ...

        progress = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);

        // ...
    }

    public void run() {
    int pos = 0;
    int total = mp.getDuration();
    while (mp != null && pos<total) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            pos = appService.getSongPosition();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
        progress.setProgress(pos);
    }
}
```

This works fine. Now I want a timer counting the seconds/minutes of the progress of the song. So I put a `TextView` in the layout, get it with `findViewById()` in `onCreate()`, and put this in `run()` after `progress.setProgress(pos)`:

```
String time = String.format("%d:%d",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(pos),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(pos),
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(
                    pos))
            );
currentTime.setText(time);  // currentTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_time);
```

But that last line gives me the exception:

> android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Yet I'm doing basically the same thing here as I'm doing with the `SeekBar` - creating the view in `onCreate`, then touching it in `run()` - and it doesn't give me this complaint.

Comment: In kotlin Add the code inside  runOnUiThread {
                                    
                                }

Comment: I don't understand why their behaviors are different? Did you declared the TextView as a global variable? If so, why does the SeekBar work but the TextView doesn't? No one answered this question.

Answer (score 2291, accepted):

You have to move the portion of the background task that updates the UI onto the main thread. There is a simple piece of code for this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // Stuff that updates the UI

    }
});
```

Documentation for [`Activity.runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)).

Just nest this inside the method that is running in the background, and then copy paste the code that implements any updates in the middle of the block. Include only the smallest amount of code possible, otherwise you start to defeat the purpose of the background thread.

Comment: worked like a charm. for me the only problem here is that I wanted to do an `error.setText(res.toString());` inside the run() method, but I couldn't use the res because it wasn't final.. too bad

Comment: One brief comment on this. I had a separate thread that was trying to modify the UI, and the above code worked, but I had call runOnUiThread from the Activity object.  I had to do something like  `myActivityObject.runOnUiThread(etc)`

Comment: @Kirby Thank you for this reference. You can simply do 'MainActivity.this' and it should work as well so you don't have to keep reference to your activity class.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out that `runOnUiThread()` is a method of Activity. I was running my code in a fragment. I ended up doing `getActivity().runOnUiThread(etc)` and it worked. Fantastic!;

Comment: Can we stop the task being performed that is written in the body of   'runOnUiThread' method ?

Comment: I was using runOnUiThread() and still getting the error. Then I found I was updating an UI element in runOnUiThread(). Removed the update portion and added mechanism to update that UI element later - fixed my problem.

Comment: This fixed 2 of my problems. 1) the same as in the question 2) a ListView not actually updating when calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().  Also, I got to up vote this answer to 1667. My OCD says this is a good thing, but I can't even remember why...  :-)

Comment: Simple and effective solution for your use case is runOnUiThread / handler

Comment: Thank you! I ran into this when using a `ProgressDialog`. It launched and did everything fine but would crash when trying to update the progress in `onProgressUpdate`. Wrapping this in `runOnUiThread` fixed it. Thanks again!

Comment: This might help for new comers..https://stackoverflow.com/a/56852228/7735068

Answer (score 162):

I solved this by putting `runOnUiThread( new Runnable(){ ..` inside `run()`:

```
thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    wait(5000);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            dbloadingInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            loadingText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    });

                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent mainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainActivity);
        };
    };  
    thread.start();
```

Comment: This one rocked. Thanks for information that, this can also be used inside any other thread.

Comment: Thank you, it's really sad to create a thread in order to go back to the UI Thread but only this solution saved my case.

Comment: One important aspect is that `wait(5000);` isn't inside the Runnable, otherwise your UI will freeze during the wait period. You should consider using [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of Thread for operations like these.

Comment: this is so bad for memory leak

Comment: Why bother with the synchronized block? The code inside it looks reasonably thread safe (although I'm fully prepared to eat my words).

Answer (score 89):

My solution to this:

```
private void setText(final TextView text,final String value){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            text.setText(value);
        }
    });
}
```

Call this method on a background thread.

Comment: Error:(73, 67) error: non-static method set(String) cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: I have the same issue with my test classes.  This worked like a charm for me.  However, replacing `runOnUiThread` with `runTestOnUiThread`.  Thanks

Answer (score 50):

Kotlin coroutines can make your code more concise and readable like this:

```
MainScope().launch {
    withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        //TODO("Background processing...")
    }
    TODO("Update UI here!")
}
```

Or vice versa:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    //TODO("Background processing...")
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        // TODO("Update UI here!")
    }
    TODO("Continue background processing...")
}
```

---

##### Update 2023/06:

Consider carefully when using [GlobalScope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65047492/1562087). If possible, create a new scope so you are able to cancel it, for ex.:

```
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + SupervisorJob())
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much for saving my day

Comment: Thanks for saving my time.

Answer (score 34):

Usually, any action involving the user interface must be done in the main or UI thread, that is the one in which `onCreate()` and event handling are executed. One way to be sure of that is using [runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)), another is using Handlers.

`ProgressBar.setProgress()` has a mechanism for which it will always execute on the main thread, so that's why it worked.

See [Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html).

Comment: The Painless Threading article at that link is now a 404. Here is a link to an (older?) blog piece on Painless Threading - http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Answer (score 27):

You can use Handler to Delete View without disturbing the main UI Thread.
Here is example code

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
          //do stuff like remove view etc
          adapter.remove(selecteditem);
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 27):

**Kotlin Answer**

We have to use UI Thread for the job with true way. We can use UI Thread in Kotlin, such as:

```
runOnUiThread(Runnable {
   //TODO: Your job is here..!
})
```

Answer (score 22):

I've been in this situation, but I found a solution with the Handler Object.

In my case, I want to update a ProgressDialog with the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).
My view implements observer and overrides the update method.

So, my main thread create the view and another thread call the update method that update the ProgressDialop and....:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views.

It's possible to solve the problem with the Handler Object.

Below, different parts of my code:

```
public class ViewExecution extends Activity implements Observer{

    static final int PROGRESS_DIALOG = 0;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    int currentNumber;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        currentNumber = 0;
        final Button launchPolicyButton =  ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.launchButton));
        launchPolicyButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch(id) {
        case PROGRESS_DIALOG:
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            return progressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
        switch(id) {
        case PROGRESS_DIALOG:
            progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        }

    }

    // Define the Handler that receives messages from the thread and update the progress
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            int current = msg.arg1;
            progressDialog.setProgress(current);
            if (current >= 100){
                removeDialog (PROGRESS_DIALOG);
            }
        }
    };

    // The method called by the observer (the second thread)
    @Override
    public void update(Observable obs, Object arg1) {

        Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = ++currentPluginNumber;
        handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

This explanation can be found on [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), and you must read the "Example ProgressDialog with a second thread".

Answer (score 8):

I see that you have accepted @providence's answer. Just in case, you can also use the handler too! First, do the int fields.

```
    private static final int SHOW_LOG = 1;
    private static final int HIDE_LOG = 0;
```

Next, make a handler instance as a field.

```
    //TODO __________[ Handler ]__________
    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    protected Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            // Put code here...

            // Set a switch statement to toggle it on or off.
            switch(msg.what)
            {
            case SHOW_LOG:
            {
                ads.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            }
            case HIDE_LOG:
            {
                ads.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            }
            }
        }
    };
```

Make a method.

```
//TODO __________[ Callbacks ]__________
@Override
public void showHandler(boolean show)
{
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(show ? SHOW_LOG : HIDE_LOG);
}
```

Finally, put this at `onCreate()` method.

```
showHandler(true);
```

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue, and my solution is ugly, but it works:

```
void showCode() {
    hideRegisterMessage(); // Hides view 
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            showRegisterMessage(); // Shows view
        }
    }, 3000); // After 3 seconds
}
```

Comment: @R.jzadeh it's nice to hear that. Since the moment I did wrote that answer, probably now you can do it better :)

Answer (score 8):

Use this code, and no need to `runOnUiThread` function:

```
private Handler handler;
private Runnable handlerTask;

void StartTimer(){
    handler = new Handler();   
    handlerTask = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override 
        public void run() { 
            // do something  
            textView.setText("some text");
            handler.postDelayed(handlerTask, 1000);    
        }
    };
    handlerTask.run();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I was facing a similar problem and none of the methods mentioned above worked for me. In the end, this did the trick for me:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        myMethod();
    });
```

I found this gem [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30804/exception-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-views).

Answer (score 7):

I use `Handler` with `Looper.getMainLooper()`. It worked fine for me.

```
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              // Any UI task, example
              textView.setText("your text");
        }
    };
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
```

Answer (score 7):

This is explicitly throwing an error. It says whichever thread created a view, only that can touch its views. It is because the created view is inside that thread's space. The view creation (GUI) happens in the UI (main) thread. So, you always use the UI thread to access those methods.

[image]

In the above picture, the progress variable is inside the space of the UI thread. So, only the UI thread can access this variable. Here, you're accessing progress via new Thread(), and that's why you got an error.

Answer (score 7):

For a one-liner version of the `runOnUiThread()` approach, you can use a lambda function, i.e.:

```java
runOnUiThread(() -> doStuff(Object, myValue));
```

where `doStuff()` can represents some method used to modify the value of some UI Object (setting text, changing colors, etc.).

I find this to be much neater when trying to update several UI objects without the need for a 6 line Runnable definition at each as mentioned in [the most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5162096/2760299), which is by no means incorrect, it just takes up a lot more space and I find to be less readable.

So this:

```java
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doStuff(myTextView, "myNewText");
    }
});
```

can become this:

```java
runOnUiThread(() -> doStuff(myTextView, "myNewText"));
```

where the definition of doStuff lies elsewhere.

Or if you don't need to be so generalizable, and just need to set the text of a TextView object:

```java
runOnUiThread(() -> myTextView.setText("myNewText"));
```

Answer (score 6):

For anyone using fragment:

```
(context as Activity).runOnUiThread {
    //TODO
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This happened to my when I called for an UI change from a `doInBackground` from `Asynctask` instead of using `onPostExecute`.

Dealing with the UI in `onPostExecute` solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. This was my issue too but I had to do a bit more reading to understand what you meant here. For anyone else, `onPostExecute` is also a method of `AsyncTask` but it runs on the UI thread. See here: https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/all-about-android-asynctasks

Answer (score 5):

I was working with a class that did not contain a reference to the context. So it was not possible for me to use `runOnUIThread();` I used `view.post();` and it was solved.

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        audioMessage.seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition / 1000);
        audioMessage.tvPlayDuration.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                audioMessage.tvPlayDuration.setText(ChatDateTimeFormatter.getDuration(currentPosition));
            }
        });
    }
}, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: What is the analogy of `audioMessage` and `tvPlayDuration` to the questions code?

Comment: `audioMessage` is a holder object of the text view. `tvPlayDuration` is the text view we want to update from a non UI thread. 
In the question above, `currentTime` is the text view but it does not have a holder object.

Answer (score 4):

When using **AsyncTask** Update the UI in **onPostExecute** method

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
   // Update UI here

     }
```

Comment: this happened to me. i was updating ui in doinbackground of asynk task.

Answer (score 3):

This is the stack trace of mentioned exception

```
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6149)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:843)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16474)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16474)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16474)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16474)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:352)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16474)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:352)
        at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:8938)
        at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:6066)
```

So if you go and dig then you come to know

```
void checkThread() {
    if (mThread != Thread.currentThread()) {
        throw new CalledFromWrongThreadException(
                "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.");
    }
}
```

Where **mThread** is initialize in constructor like below

```
mThread = Thread.currentThread();
```

**All I mean to say that when we created particular view we created it on UI Thread and later try to modifying in a Worker Thread.**

We can verify it via below code snippet

```
Thread.currentThread().getName()
```

when we inflate layout and later where you are getting exception.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to use `runOnUiThread` API, you can in fact implement `AsynTask` for the operations that takes some seconds to complete. But in that case, also after processing your work in `doinBackground()`, you need to return the finished view in `onPostExecute()`. The Android implementation allows only main UI thread to interact with views.

Answer (score 3):

**If you are using Kotlin Coroutine, please try this code:**

```
GlobalScope.launch {
        
       //Write a background operation
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    
                 // write a UI operation
    
             }
     
      `enter code here`}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to invalidate (call repaint/redraw function) from your non UI Thread, use postInvalidate()

```
myView.postInvalidate();
```

This will post an invalidate request on the UI-thread.

For more information : [what-does-postinvalidate-do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521596/what-does-postinvalidate-do)

Answer (score 2):

Well, You can do it like this.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#post(java.lang.Runnable)

A simple approach

```
currentTime.post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 currentTime.setText(time);     
            }
        }
```

it also provides delay

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)

Comment: Glad to see you posting answers! Do keep in mind that you are expected to add some details about what you fixed or why it is right. It helps users understand what is going on, rather than just being served the answer. Consider it a rule for all your answers here. I hope you have a good time.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that I was calling `onProgressUpdate()` explicitly from my code. This shouldn't be done. I called `publishProgress()` instead and that resolved the error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case,
I have `EditText` in Adaptor, and it's already in the UI thread. However, when this Activity loads, it's crashes with this error.

My solution is I need to remove `<requestFocus />` out from EditText in XML.

Answer (score 1):

For the people struggling in Kotlin, it works like this:

```
lateinit var runnable: Runnable //global variable

 runOnUiThread { //Lambda
            runnable = Runnable {

                //do something here

                runDelayedHandler(5000)
            }
        }

        runnable.run()

 //you need to keep the handler outside the runnable body to work in kotlin
 fun runDelayedHandler(timeToWait: Long) {

        //Keep it running
        val handler = Handler()
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, timeToWait)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you couldn't find a UIThread you can use this way .

**yourcurrentcontext** mean, you need to parse Current Context

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                (Activity) yourcurrentcontext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() { 
                        Log.d("Thread Log","I am from UI Thread");
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Kotlin** simply put your code in runOnUiThread activity method

```
runOnUiThread{
    // write your code here, for example
    val task = Runnable {
            Handler().postDelayed({
                var smzHtcList = mDb?.smzHtcReferralDao()?.getAll()
                tv_showSmzHtcList.text = smzHtcList.toString()
            }, 10)

        }
    mDbWorkerThread.postTask(task)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are within a fragment, then you also need to get the activity object as runOnUIThread is a method on the activity.

An example in Kotlin with some surrounding context to make it clearer - this example is navigating from a camera fragment to a gallery fragment:

```js
// Setup image capture listener which is triggered after photo has been taken
imageCapture.takePicture(
       outputOptions, cameraExecutor, object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {

           override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
           Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
        }

        override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                        val savedUri = output.savedUri ?: Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                        Log.d(TAG, "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri")
               
             //Do whatever work you do when image is saved         
             
             //Now ask navigator to move to new tab - as this
             //updates UI do on the UI thread           
             activity?.runOnUiThread( {
                 Navigation.findNavController(
                        requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container
                 ).navigate(CameraFragmentDirections
                        .actionCameraToGallery(outputDirectory.absolutePath))
              })
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the caller calls too many times in short time will get this error, I simply put elapsed time checking to do nothing if too short, e.g. ignore if function get called less than 0.5 second:

```
    private long mLastClickTime = 0;

    public boolean foo() {
        if ( (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime) < 500) {
            return false;
        }
        mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

        //... do ui update
    }
```

Comment: Better solution would be to disable the button on click and enable it again when the action completes.

Comment: @lsrom In my case is not that simple because the caller is 3rd party library internal and out of my control.

Answer (score 0):

Solved : Just put this method in doInBackround Class... and pass the message

```
public void setProgressText(final String progressText){
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // Any UI task, example
                progressDialog.setMessage(progressText);
            }
        };
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

RunOnUIThread didn't seem to work for me but the following ended up solving my issues.

```
            _ = MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () =>
           {
               this.LoadApplication(Startup.Init(this.ConfigureServices));

               var authenticationService = App.ServiceProvider.GetService<AuthenticationService>();
               if (authenticationService.AuthenticationResult == null)
               {
                   await authenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(AuthenticationUserFlow.SignUpSignIn, CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity).ConfigureAwait(false);
               }
           });
```

Within the Startup.Init method there is ReactiveUI routing and this needs to be invoked on the main thread. This Invoke method also accepts async/await better than RunOnUIThread.

So anywhere I need to invoke methods on the mainthread I use this.

Please comment on this if anyone knows something I don't and can help me improve my application.

Answer (score 0):

'Esse é meu codigo'

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    KeyValuePair<String, String> keyValuePair = getCalculateDifferenceBetweenTwoTimes();

                    CharSequence charSequence = getPresenterUtil().contact(
                            getPresenterUtil().messageStyle("Check-in", Color.GRAY, Typeface.NORMAL, 0.9f),
                            UtilPresenter.LINE,
                            getPresenterUtil().messageStyle(keyValuePair.getKey(), Color.BLACK, Typeface.NORMAL, 1.3f),
                            UtilPresenter.LINE,
                            UtilPresenter.LINE,
                            getPresenterUtil().messageStyle("Tempo de execução", Color.GRAY, Typeface.NORMAL, 0.9f),
                            UtilPresenter.LINE,
                            getPresenterUtil().messageStyle(keyValuePair.getValue(), Color.BLACK, Typeface.NORMAL, 1.3f)
                    );

                    if (materialDialog.getContentView() != null) {
                        materialDialog.getContentView().setText(charSequence);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

if your are using the coroutines for and doing in the IO thread and then where ever are post the UI then use

**Dispatcher.Main** to update the thread.

```
withContext(Dispatcher.Main){

//update the UI

}
```