# What does postInvalidate() do?

Tags: android, android-layout, invalidation

What is the use of the `postInvalidate()` function in Android? I have been seeing this function in a lot of places. When I Googled, I came out with this much:

> postInvalidate-- *post an invalidate request on the UI-thread*

I don't know what the phrase "invalidate request" there means. Can someone explain in detail what is happening here?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Each class which is derived from the View class has the **invalidate** and the **postInvalidate** method. If invalidate gets called it tells the system that the current view has changed and it should be redrawn as soon as possible. As this method can only be called from your UIThread another method is needed for when you are not in the UIThread and still want to notify the system that your View has been changed. The postInvalidate method notifies the system from a non-UIThread and the View gets redrawn in the next eventloop on the UIThread as soon as possible. It is also [briefly explained](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) in the SDK documentation.

Just compare **invalidate** and **postInvalidate**.

Comment: I see the logics in your answer, but invalidate() also works in my non-UI class. Works just as fine as postInvalidate().

Comment: Great answer. The Android docs doesn't explain that its meant to redraw the View. Cleared it right up :)

Comment: As @Sebastian mentioned, I also tried both `invalidate()` and `postInvalidate()` from a non-UI thread (using `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`), but both of them works fine, at least there seems no problem. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 24):

By this method (`postInvalidate()`), you can invalidate a `View` from non-UI threads. To invalidate a `View` from UI-thread use `invalidate()` method.

The invalidation means, that the `View.onDraw(Canvas)` method will we called at some point in the future (not immediately) to redraw whole `View` (if the `View` is visible).

Android is redrawing `View`s automaticly, but sometimes is necessary to tell: "Hey, this `View` has been changed, redraw it as fast as possible."

More at:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29

Answer (score 4):

In simple words, `invalidate()` method can be called from UI Thread and `postInvalidate()` can be called from non-UI Thread in order to tell android to update our Custom View after some changes are made to it.