# android textview not changing the text

Tags: android

i got a textview which should changes the text after the intent (directorypicker) finish.that doesn't work.
heres the code:

```
text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choose3);
        text.setText(globalconstant.path);
```

should change the text when the intent returns the path:

```
private void addListenerOnButton() {
        choose_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        choose_button.setEnabled(true);
        choose_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // DirectoryPicker.START_DIR = "/mnt/";
                Intent intent = new Intent(settings.this, DirectoryPicker.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, DirectoryPicker.PICK_DIRECTORY);
                // text.setText(globalconstant.path);
                text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choose3);
                text.setText(globalconstant.path);
                ;

            }
        });

    }
```

whats wrong with it? 
please help me!
Thank you very much

Comment: It would be better if you can present the complete code. What is the `DirectoryPicker` doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, you should change the text in `onActivityResult`

Comment: how? please give me exaple :/

Comment: @user1620554 Sure, if you tell me what DirectoryPicker is. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with DirectoryPicker

Comment: @user1620554 : `onActivityResult(...)` see this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)

Comment: @user1620554 So, override onActivityResult, get Intent parameter and get a string from it and update your textview with that string

Comment: found the onactivityresulton the main page :D http://www.bgreco.net/directorypicker/readme.html

Answer (score 0):

First test if you code work, replace `text.setText(globalconstant.path);` with `text.setText("Test message");` is this work or not.

Then you can add a `Log.d("TestAfterStartAct", "Test Message")` open the commandos line and run `adb logcat` for show the log from the phone. Try to note while is the code run, before/after/never after the new Activity is show?

Some times you can get error with no updates GUI parts if the edit not is do from a UI thread, call for you `text.postInvalidate()` for update the GUI for the textview.

Read more on [What does postInvalidate() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521596/what-does-postinvalidate-do)

Comment: there is no log after the intent finish

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  The issue for me was that onStart is called when after onActivityResult was called.  In the onStart I was inflating the view which was creating a new textview, with the default values.

In my case I solved it by saving the values in the onActivityResult and then apply the values in the onStart function.
-James