# Android MediaRecorder Visualizer

Tags: android, android-studio, audio, visualization, android-mediarecorder

I use [this VisualizerView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34551064/6296729) in my project but if I have a short recording, the visualization ends before the end of the screen. The following screenshoot shows how it looks: [image: short recording]

If I have long recording (more than about 40 second) VisualiserView look like this (it ends almost at the end of screen): [image: long recording]

I want to VisualizerView width will be the same as screen width and its duration will be the same as recording duration
(recording duration is always known before recording).

**How can I fix it?**

Comment: Ask the question to the person from whom your copied the code from?

Comment: But that code is from over one year ago.. I hope that someone know answer for my question here.