# Can MediaRecorder save voice as mp3 or m4a audio format file automatically based file name extension in Android Studio?

Tags: android

The following Code A is from the sample [project](https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Voice-Recorder/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/com/simplemobiletools/voicerecorder/services/RecorderService.kt).

It use the Code B to record voice and save as file.

**Code B**

```
setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
```

You know the `getExtensionText()` will return two audio format, mp3 or m4a by user settings , there are different audio format.

I don't know why the author can use only Code B to generate two different audio format file.

Can MediaRecorder save voice as mp3 or m4a audio format file automatically based file name extension in Android Studio?

**Code A**

```
    // mp4 output format with aac encoding should produce good enough m4a files according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33054794/1967672
    private fun startRecording() {
        val baseFolder = if (isQPlus()) {
            cacheDir
        } else {
            val defaultFolder = File(config.saveRecordingsFolder)
            if (!defaultFolder.exists()) {
                defaultFolder.mkdir()
            }

            defaultFolder.absolutePath
        }

        currFilePath = "$baseFolder/${getCurrentFormattedDateTime()}.${config.getExtensionText()}"
        recorder = MediaRecorder().apply {
            setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER)
            setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
            setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
            setAudioEncodingBitRate(128000)
            setAudioSamplingRate(44100)

         ...

      }



  class Config(context: Context) : BaseConfig(context) {
    ...

   
    fun getExtensionText() = context.getString(when (extension) {
        EXTENSION_M4A -> R.string.m4a
        else -> R.string.mp3
    })
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, they already defined the file extension in the `SettingsActivity.kt` but you can use the file name with the extension. Actually, In this code, you can use any extension of the [supported media formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats).

```
        mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()
        output = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/recording.mp3"

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(output)
```

for the full code see [this](https://gabrieltanner.org/blog/sound-recorder) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295427/android-audio-recording-with-voice-level-visualization/30093929#30093929)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, they already defined the file extension  mp3 or m4a, but can `setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)`  generate different  audio format by file extension ?

Comment: I already updated the answer and I hope that answer your question.