# Loading 2 Web Views on Single Activity in android

Tags: android, webview, thread-safety, viewroot

I have the following code, which will load two different web view upon request.

```
public class MultipleWebViewHanlder {  
public MultipleWebViewHanlder(Context context) {   
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub  
        this.context = context;  
            }  

public void MultipleWebViewfun(final String str) {

final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);  

            final WebView mWebView = new WebView(context);  

            WebSettings settings=mWebView.getSettings(); 
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
            settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);  
            settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);  
            settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);  

            settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);  
            mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());  



             JSInterface.handler.post(new Runnable() {  

                @Override  
                public void run() {  
                    try {  


                        ((Activity)context).addContentView(mWebView, params);  
                                            mWebView.loadUrl(((Activity)context).getResources().getString(R.string.DemoURL));  

                                        } catch (Exception e) {  
                         // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
                         e.printStackTrace();  
                   }
public class HybridActivity extends Activity {  
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
            WebView webview = new WebView(this);  
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
  webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/html/hyb.html");  
            setContentView(webview);  

        MultipleWebViewHanlder webView2 = new MultipleWebViewHanlder (this);
        webView2.MultipleWebViewfun();
```

And I am getting the following exception:

WebView Core Thread Exception:

```
android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

My log:

```
04-24 15:32:08.764: WARN/dalvikvm(13212): threadid=8: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0)  
04-24 15:32:08.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13212): FATAL EXCEPTION: WebViewCoreThread  
04-24 15:32:08.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13212): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.  
04-24 15:32:08.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13212):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2826)  
04-24 15:32:08.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13212):     at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:616)  
04-24 15:32:08.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13212):     at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:642)  
04-24 15:32:08.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13212):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2505)  
04-24 15:32:08.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13212):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5115)  
04-24 15:32:08.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13212):     at android.webkit.WebView.viewInvalidate(WebView.java:2616)  
04-24 15:32:08.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13212):     at android.webkit.WebView.invalidateContentRect(WebView.java:2635)  
04-24 15:32:08.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13212):     at android.webkit.WebView.access$6400(WebView.java:300)  
04-24 15:32:08.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13212):     at android.webkit.WebView$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(WebView.java:8072)  
04-24 15:32:08.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13212):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
04-24 15:32:08.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13212):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)  
04-24 15:32:08.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13212):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:691)  
04-24 15:32:08.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13212):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)  
04-24 15:32:08.772: WARN/ActivityManager(2490):   Force finishing activity com.Hy5/.activity.Hy5CanvasActivity
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe if you put that code inside this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //stuff that updates ui
    }
});
```

it will work

Answer (score 0):

See: [Android "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi)

Your issue stems from here:

```
JSInterface.handler.post(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {  
           try {  
               ((Activity)context).addContentView(mWebView, params); 
               ...
```

You're attempting to add the webView to the context outside of the main thread. You should be able to nest your UI logic in the code block `Activity.runOnUiThread`