# Running code in main thread from another thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-handler

In an android service I have created thread(s) for doing some background task.

I have a situation where a thread needs to post certain task on main thread's message queue, for example a `Runnable`.

Is there a way to get `Handler` of the main thread and post `Message`/`Runnable` to it from my other thread?

Comment: You can also use Custom broadcast receiver....try my answer here,
[Inner Broadcast Receiver][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22541324/1881527

Comment: There are many ways. Apart from David's answer & dzeikei's comment in his answer, (3) you can use a Broadcast Receiver, or (4) pass the handler in extras of Intent used to start the service, and then retrieve the main thread's handler inside service using getIntent().getExtras() .

Comment: @sazzad-hissain-khan, Why tag this question from 2012 with mostly answers in Java with the kotlin tag?

Answer (score 699, accepted):

NOTE: This answer has gotten so much attention, that I need to update it. Since the original answer was posted, the comment from @dzeikei has gotten almost as much attention as the original answer. So here are 2 possible solutions:

**1. If your background thread has a reference to a `Context` object:**

Make sure that your background worker threads have access to a Context object (can be the Application context or the Service context). Then just do this in the background worker thread:

```
// Get a handler that can be used to post to the main thread
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());

Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {....} // This is your code
};
mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
```

**2. If your background thread does not have (or need) a `Context` object**

(suggested by @dzeikei):

```
// Get a handler that can be used to post to the main thread
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {....} // This is your code
};
mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
```

Comment: Thanks David it worked out for me, one more thing if you could help me with, if I extend Handler and impl handleMessage() would it prevent main thread from handling its messages ? that's only a question out of curosity..

Comment: No. If you subclass `Handler` (or use `Handler.Callback` interface) your `handleMessage()` method will ONLY be called for messages that have been posted using your handler. The main thread is using a different handler to post/process messages so there is no conflict.

Comment: I believe you won't even need context if you use `Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());`

Comment: Minor point; your code doesn't go where the ... currently is. It should be `new Runnable(){@Override public void run() {....}};`

Comment: @DavidWasser thank you very much your code does exactly what i want but just a query. I am using this code to get the location of the user in the splashScreen. How can i set a boolean variable to check if i have got a response depending on which i decide the next activity to be started.

Comment: @SagarDevanga This is not the right place to ask a different question. Please post a new question , not a comment to an unrelated answer. You will get better and faster response that way.

Comment: If you don't want to use a Runnable just do it this way:
Message msg = mainHandler.obtainMessage();
msg.sendToTarget(); //Don't use dispatchMessage

Comment: If you have access to the activity then you can call the runOnUiThread() method to post runnable to be executed on the UI thread from another thread.

Answer (score 163):

As a commenter below pointed correctly, this is not a general solution for services, only for threads launched from your activity (a service can be such a thread, but not all of those are).
On the complicated topic of service-activity communication please read the whole Services section of the official doc - it is complex, so it would pay to understand the basics:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Notifications

The method below may work in the simplest cases:

If I understand you correctly you need some code to be executed in the GUI thread of the application (cannot think about anything else called "main" thread).
For this there is a method on `Activity`:

```
someActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           //Your code to run in GUI thread here
        }//public void run() {
});
```

Doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: OP says he is running threads in a `Service`. You cannot use `runOnUiThread()` in a `Service`. This answer is misleading and doesn't address the asked question.

Answer (score 102):

### Kotlin versions

When **you are on an activity**, then use

```
runOnUiThread {
    //code that runs in main
}
```

When **you have activity context**, mContext then use

```
mContext.runOnUiThread {
    //code that runs in main
}
```

When you are in somewhere **outside activity** where **no context available**, then use

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {  
    //code that runs in main
}
```

Comment: Not sure what version of Kotlin this is, but I had to add braces : `runOnUiThread(){...}`

Comment: Works greatly for me using Android Studio 4.1.1 on mac.

Comment: is it safe to always create a new instance of Handler?

Answer (score 32):

There is another simple way, if you don't have an access to the Context.

1). Create a handler from the main looper:

```
Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

2). Implement a Runnable interface:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() { // your code here }
```

3). Post your Runnable to the uiHandler:

```
uiHandler.post(runnable);
```

That's all ;-) Have fun with threads, but don't forget to synchronize them.

Answer (score 31):

A condensed code block is as follows:

```
   new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           // things to do on the main thread
       }
   });
```

This does not involve passing down the Activity reference or the Application reference.

Kotlin Equivalent:

```
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(Runnable {
        // things to do on the main thread
    })
```

Answer (score 29):

If you run code in a thread, e.g. do delaying some action, then you need to invoke `runOnUiThread` from the context. For example, if your code is inside `MainActivity` class then use this:

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myAction();
    }
});
```

If your method can be invoked either from main (UI thread) or from other threads you need a check like:

```
public void myMethod() {
   if( Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper() ) {
       myAction();
   }
   else {

}
```

Comment: OP says he is running threads in a `Service`. You cannot use `runOnUiThread()` in a `Service`.

Comment: @DavidWasser Is that documented anywhere? The method docs don't mention anything about it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29

Comment: @GregBrown As you've indicated by your link to the `Activity` documentation, `runOnUiThread()` is a method of `Activity`. It is not a method of `Service`, therefore you cannot use it. What could be clearer than that?

Comment: @DavidWasser Fair enough. I don't even remember why I asked that question now (it was posted almost a year ago).

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question, but I came across a main thread one-liner that I use in both Kotlin and Java. This may not be the best solution for a service, but for calling something that will change the UI inside of a fragment this is extremely simple and obvious.

Java (8):

```
 getActivity().runOnUiThread(()->{
      //your main thread code
 });
```

Kotlin:

```
this.runOnUiThread {
     //your main thread code
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`HandlerThread` is better option to normal java Threads in Android .

1. Create a [HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) and start it
2. Create a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) with [Looper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) from HandlerThread :`requestHandler`
3. `post` a `Runnable` task on `requestHandler`

Communication with UI Thread from `HandlerThread`

1. Create a `Handler` with `Looper` for main thread  :  `responseHandler` and override `handleMessage` method
2. Inside `Runnable` task of other Thread ( `HandlerThread` in this case), call `sendMessage` on `responseHandler`
3. This `sendMessage` result invocation of `handleMessage` in `responseHandler`.
4. Get attributes from the `Message` and process it, update UI

**Example**: Update `TextView` with data received from a web service. Since web service should be invoked on non-UI thread, created `HandlerThread` for Network Operation. Once you get the content from the web service, send message to your main thread (UI Thread) handler and that `Handler` will handle the message and update UI.

Sample code:

```
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("NetworkOperation");
handlerThread.start();
Handler requestHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());

final Handler responseHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        txtView.setText((String) msg.obj);
    }
};

Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.d("Runnable", "Before IO call");
            URL page = new URL("http://www.your_web_site.com/fetchData.jsp");
            StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) page.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader((InputStream) conn.getContent());
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(in);
            String line;
            while ((line = buff.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line + "\n");
            }
            Log.d("Runnable", "After IO call:"+ text.toString());
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.obj = text.toString();
            responseHandler.sendMessage(msg);


        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
requestHandler.post(myRunnable);
```

Useful articles:

[handlerthreads-and-why-you-should-be-using-them-in-your-android-apps](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/handlerthreads-and-why-you-should-be-using-them-in-your-android-apps-dc8bf1540341)

[android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i](https://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/11/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i/)

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way especially if you don't have a context, if you're using RxAndroid you can do:

```
AndroidSchedulers.mainThread().scheduleDirect {
    runCodeHere()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

More precise Kotlin code using handler :

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {  
 // your codes here run on main Thread
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

```kotlin
ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context).execute {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One method I can think of is this:

1) Let the UI bind to the service.
2) Expose a method like the one below by the `Binder` that registers your `Handler`:

```
public void registerHandler(Handler handler) {
    mHandler = handler;
}
```

3) In the UI thread, call the above method after binding to the service:

```
mBinder.registerHandler(new Handler());
```

4) Use the handler in the Service's thread to post your task:

```
mHandler.post(runnable);
```

Answer (score 4):

So most handy is to do sort of:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper

object Dispatch {
    fun asyncOnBackground(call: ()->Unit) {
        AsyncTask.execute {
            call()
        }
    }

    fun asyncOnMain(call: ()->Unit) {
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
            call()
        }
    }
}
```

And after:

```
Dispatch.asyncOnBackground {
    val value = ...// super processing
    Dispatch.asyncOnMain { completion(value)}
}
```

Comment: AsyncTask seems to be depricated

Answer (score 2):

Follow this method. Using this way you can simply update the UI from a background thread. runOnUiThread work on the main(UI) thread . I think this code snippet is less complex and easy, especially for beginners.

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            //code you want to run on the background
            someCode();

           //the code you want to run on main thread
 MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {

/*the code you want to run after the background operation otherwise they will executed earlier and give you an error*/
                        executeAfterOperation();

                   }
                });
            }
        });
```

in the case of a service

create a handler in the oncreate

```
 handler = new Handler();
```

then use it like this

```
 private void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
        handler.post(runnable);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

for Kotlin, you can use [Anko corountines](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Coroutines):

**update**

```
doAsync {
   ...
}
```

**deprecated**

```
async(UI) {
    // Code run on UI thread
    // Use ref() instead of this@MyActivity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void mainWork() {
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Add Your Code Here
        }
    });
}
```

This can also work in a service class with no issue.

Comment: While this code might answer the question you still might consider adding a few explanatory sentences as this increases the value of your answer for other users!