# Repeating an AnimatorSet animation multiple times

Tags: android, android-animation

I've been trying for hours, I feel it's time to give up.
How can I loop an AnimatorSet defined in xml?

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <objectAnimator />

    <objectAnimator />

    <objectAnimator />

    <objectAnimator />

</set>
```

I tried dozens of combinations of `startOffset`, `repeatCount` and `duration` on the single `objectAnimator`s, but that's just not the right way.

I read about [this](http://www.jefflinwood.com/2013/04/repeating-android-animations-with-animatorset/) promising workaround:

```
a.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        animation.start();
        Log.i();
    }
});
```

but it just doesn't work: `onAnimationEnd` is called one time, animation is repeated, and then `onAnimationEnd` is not called anymore.

Other similar questions here involve wrong answers (referring to the `android.view.animation` framework) or suggest defining a custom interpolator for a single `objectAnimator`, but that's not really what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue with an `AnimatorSet` that played two animations together.

I created the set with `animationSet.play(anim1).with(anim2)`, which resulted in my animations only repeating a single time.

Changing it to `animationSet.play(anim1).with(anim2).after(0)` resolved my problem and allowed the animation to loop indefinitely.

It appears as though there is a bug that forces you to have at least one sequential step in the animation before animations can loop more than once.

Comment: I have no time to test it anymore, I'm going to trust you. :-)

Comment: you saved my day, don't know why **animatorSet.playTogether** does not work properly (for real devices).

Comment: First I used `animatorSet.playSequentially` which worked (looped infinite) but realized that I don't need two animations and tried `animatorSet.play` which looped only once as you describe. Using `animatorSet.play(anim1).after(0)` works for me for once animation.

Answer (score 3):

I meet absolutely the same situation. After nearly trial of a day, I suddenly suspect that animator should be started on main thread. And it works.

```
mRandomPointAnimatorSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onAnimationStart");
            mRandomPointView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onAnimationEnd");
            mRandomPointView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (isShown()) {
                        requestLayout();
                        mRandomPointAnimatorSet.start();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Current I don't know why.

Comment: I guess you should mention to pay attention to create the `mHandler` using the main thread. Like `Handler mHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11125271/

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding listener to your animation, when you are restarting animation as recursion. You need create a AnimatorListenerAdapter  object, and reuse it.

Hope I am making some sense to you!

Comment: I tried calling `a.start()` rather than `animation.start()` and I was getting the same behaviour, so I think that's not the problem. Will try!

Comment: I just create an AnimatorListenerAdapter object, add it as a listener, and start. Inside the listener I have tried calling `animation.start()` as well as `a.start()` (my final AnimatorSet), and also tried adding the listener right before. Result: `onAnimationEnd` gets triggered just one time.

Comment: Well, first up you need to believe that your IDE has no grudges with you and what ever you have tried is wrong and you need a fresh approach

!!