# How can I do sth on the end of updating?

Tags: android, okhttp

There is my code and action after `sink.close();` should change text of the textview but it isn't happening. Why?

```
protected void runNet() throws IOException {
        try{
        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://uprojects.pl/radiowezel/questions.db")
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            QuestionsDB db = new QuestionsDB(context);
        File downloadedFile = new File(context.getDatabasePath("questions.db"), "");

        BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(downloadedFile));
        sink.writeAll(response.body().source());

        sink.close();
        status.setText("Baza została zaktualizowana");


    }catch(UnknownHostException e){
        status.setText ("Brak połączenia przy pobieraniu");
    }
}
```

Comment: as I understand `runNet()` runs in background thread, you cannot update UI from background thread.

Comment: Yes, it is running in background thread. So what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update UI from background thread which is not allowed in Android, you should update it from main thread.

You can use `runOnUiThread` method (part of `Activity` class)

```
private void updateUi(final String string) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            status.setText(string);
        }
    });
}
```

you can use followed method, call it from background thread like this:

```
updateUi("Baza została zaktualizowana");
```

Or use `AsyncTask` which has callback which runs after execution on main thread - [AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Also you can use `Handler` - [Running code in main thread from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123621/running-code-in-main-thread-from-another-thread)