# Admob banner slow down the app and doing too many work on main thread - Android

Tags: android, admob

I have an activity that contain RecycleView with maximum 30 items. Every item contains 2 to 3 text views and 1 button. I have animation on clicking the button.

Before adding admob banner, the performance was really good, scrolling was smooth.

After adding admob banner, the scroll is cutting, clicking the button take a bit to respond. Aditionally, i see message shows me that Too many work on main thread!

Is there any suggestion about how to fix it ? Or what can help making it better ? 
How can I get smooth scrolling with admob banner enabled?

Hopefully I am not the only one facing this problem!

**UPDATE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:paddingBottom="64dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:id="@+id/rv_Test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: We need a little more explanation I think. Where is the admob banner located? is it in a separate view? for example, <LinearLayout..><RecycleView>...</RecycleView><AdMobView (I don't know name)>..</AdMobView> ?

Comment: Can you post where you banner is located? You are calling this banner in your adapter view? Post your adapter code and the part you are calling the banner.

Comment: @SaehunSeanOh  this is the layout

Comment: I think is nothing relationed with the banner, i think you are doing heavy process  in your onBindViewHolder  and may your animation is too heavy to run in the `Main Thread` when you click in the button. Consider put it in a `Separated Thread`, like `Runnable` , check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/11123621/1879661

Comment: @diogojme animation can be done out of main thread ?

Answer (score 3):

It Seams that `adView` is the problem than 
I have replaced the `adView` with `NativeContentAdView` to use the *Native Ads*

Now the scroll is smooth

This is the link of the doc
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native

Answer (score 0):

Admob takes some time to load the ads in start so load ads with some delay after activity transition animation is completed :

```
Handler handler = new Handler ();
handler.postDelayed (new Runnable () {
 @Override
 public void run () {
      AdRequest bannerRequest = new AdRequest.Builder (). Build ();
      mAdView.loadAd (bannerRequest);
 }
}, 2000);
```