# Calling ViewPager fragment method from service:Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android, service, android-viewpager, fragment

In my main activity i am using a view pager which shows two fragments. One for recent messages and another online contacts. In my contact fragment i am binding activity to a service named ContactService. ContactService has an interface FragmentConnected which has a public method like this:

interface FragmentConnected {

```
        public void onFragmentConnected(ArrayList<Contact> clist);
```

}

In my ContactFragment i am implementing this interface like this

public void onFragmentConnected(ArrayList clist) {

```
                      onlineContactAdapter.changeList(clist);
           }
```

Here onlineContactAdapter is my adpter for ContactFragment has a method changeList for updating list of online users.

In my service ContactService in onHandleIntent i am getting list of online users from server and i am calling method contactFragment.onFragmentConnected as i have instance of ContactFragment in contactFragment when it binds to service.
EveryThing is running fine until i call this method onFragmentConnected from service . When i am calling this method from service it is giving me this error:-  android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: Your service is calling your callback from a different thread than the main thread... it seems. So your activity service callback is getting called on a background thread causing that issue. I would recommend that you call your service callback from the main thread.

Comment: But i have to update online contact list from service so how can i can call this method from service as UI MainThread? Is there any method?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you implemented your ContactService. But your data pull from a server is happening on a background thread. After you get that data you post to send your updates via the main thread. There many ways you can do that. Most easy using Handler. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123621/running-code-in-main-thread-from-another-thread

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just made Handler object and post a thread into post method and then i called my ui method from this thread and it worked.

Comment: Great! I'm just adding my response as an answer I guess... :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you implemented your ContactService. But your data pull from a server is happening on a background thread. After you get that data you need to post to send your updates via the main thread. There many ways you can do that.

Most easy using Handler.
[Running code in main thread from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123621/running-code-in-main-thread-from-another-thread)