# android: how the thread in this code is able to access the UI element directly

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a an Activity which updates the seekbar for the mediaplayer. I found this code on internet.

```
public class SampleDownload extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable {
    private Seekbar seeekbar;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        startMedia = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        stopMedia = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        startMedia.setOnClickListener(this);
        stopMedia.setOnClickListener(this);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        seekBar.setEnabled(false);
    }

       ...... code contiunes not shown here

    @
    Override
    public void run() {
        int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
        int total = mp.getDuration();

        while (mp != null && currentPosition < total) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }
            seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
        }

    }




}
```

If this thread is running on a seperate thread other than the UI. how is it able to change seekbar

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123621/running-code-in-main-thread-from-another-thread

Comment: But how come without using any hanldler, the code is working in this case

Comment: `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                //Do something on UiThread
            }
        });`


Source [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread)

Comment: I understand all that things. But here without any such need the code is working. the thread is able to pass things. Thats what is suprising. So how this code is working. I am not how to make this code work. This is a working code.

Comment: Is your question "why is this code working although the docs say don't update gui from a non-gui-thread" ?

Comment: Yes. thats exactly is my question

Comment: How is the run() method started inside your activity? It seems like you're already running it in the main thread.

Comment: because when i implement runnable it got added automatically