# Android Add Map Marker Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker

I'm subscribing to a data stream that gets pushed coordinates, I want to place a marker on the map every time the listener gets a new point. What do I need to do to put the drawMarker code on the correct thread or in the correct scope?

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        enableMyLocation();
        subscribe();
    }

    public void drawLatestPoint(LatLng p) {
        System.out.println(p);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(p).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    }

    private void subscribe(){
        pubNub.subscribe()
                .channels(Arrays.asList("my_channel")) // subscribe to channel groups
                .execute();

        pubNub.addListener(new SubscribeCallback() {

            @Override
            public void message(PubNub pubnub, PNMessageResult message) {
                if (message.getMessage().get("lat") != null && message.getMessage().get("lng") != null) {
                    double lat = message.getMessage().get("lat").doubleValue();
                    double lng = message.getMessage().get("lng").doubleValue();
                    LatLng point = new LatLng(lat,lng);
                    drawLatestPoint(point);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `runOnUiThread` to run the code in the GUI thread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       // Your code to run in GUI thread here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize you could simply invoke other threads.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your pubsub has access to a Context object (can be the Application context or the Service context). Then put the required code inside the `run` method :

```
// Get a handler that can be used to post to the main thread
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());

Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {....} // This is your code
};
mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123621/running-code-in-main-thread-from-another-thread)

Comment: Where is Handler coming from? AS tells me it doesn't exist.

Comment: [android.os.Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) is a class in the Android framework.