# How to track android fragments using firebase analytics

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-analytics

In my android application, I have an Activity that has 3 or 4 fragments that can be attached in sequence based on some user or server events.

I would like to track all these fragments as screens in firebase.

So ideally, if possible, is there an API i can invoke in the onCreate of the fragments, and tell firebase that user is currently in fragment1, fragment2 or fragment3?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Since the `setCurrentScreen` is deprecated, you can use `logEvent` method

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_CLASS, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SCREEN_VIEW, bundle);
```

I've used the following adb commands to check if all is working fine.

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

Once you do that you'll see `screen_view` events in the logcat. Like this one:

> 10-15 13:14:13.744 V/FA-SVC  (20323): Logging event:
> origin=app,name=**screen_view**(_vs),params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=app,
> engagement_time_msec(_et)=31600,
> ga_previous_class(_pc)=ContentsFragment,
> ga_previous_id(_pi)=8077407744361472421,
> ga_previous_screen(_pn)=ContentsFragment,
> ga_screen_class(_sc)=**TestFragment**,
> ga_screen_id(_si)=8077407744361472423, ga_screen(_sn)=**TestFragment**}]

**Previous answer**

There is a special method to set a current screen - [`setCurrentScreen`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews)

I used it as follows

```
mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(this, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName(), fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

Once the method is called, the following message appears in the LogCat

> Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs),
> Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
> firebase_previous_class(_pc)=HomeFragment,
> firebase_previous_id(_pi)=4121566113087629222,
> firebase_previous_screen(_pn)=HomeFragment,
> firebase_screen_class(_sc)=StatisticsFragment,
> firebase_screen_id(_si)=4121566113087629223,
> firebase_screen(_sn)=StatisticsFragment}]

The following event appears on auto activity tracking:

> Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs),
> Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
> firebase_previous_class(_pc)=StatisticsFragment,
> firebase_previous_id(_pi)=4121566113087629223,
> firebase_previous_screen(_pn)=StatisticsFragment,
> firebase_screen_class(_sc)=LoginActivity,
> firebase_screen_id(_si)=4121566113087629224}]

As you see, they are almost the same, so `setCurrentScreen` is working.

I'm able to see those classes in Firebase Console only on the next day. It is normal for Firebase - it takes time to process such amounts of data.

[image: Firebase Console]

Comment: Where do you think the best place is to call this method? In `onStart`, `onResume`, or another method? (in a fragment)

Comment: `onResume` is the best option, I think. As it is called when you're returning to the fragment from another one.

Comment: you can track it during 60seconds:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7201382?hl=en&utm_id=ad&authuser=0

Comment: Must be called on UI thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48117692/1177083

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev what about tracking the activity the fragment is placed in? Are you tracking even that? If yes, activity's screenview will be followed by the fragment's, right?

Comment: @Charan Activities are tracked automatically, the order of this events depends when you call `setCurrentScreen` in activity lifecycle.

Comment: `setCurrentScreen` is deprecated :(

Comment: how they track time? I mean if I log only for one fragment, how they know when I leave that fragment if I don't log other screen events?

Comment: I suppose only when you send the next logEvent with a screen.

Answer (score 13):

Adding a some more insight here to Artem Mostyaev answer. GA/Firebase panel was reflecting the class name in DEV version but not on PROD version.The main culprit here is

```
fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

which obfuscate the fragment name in prod. So GA/Firebase was showing classname to be like (a,b,ah, etc)

getSimpleName() is also dangerous to use in other situation.

More literature : https://medium.com/@elye.project/the-danger-of-using-class-getsimplename-as-tag-for-fragment-5cdf3a35bfe2

Progaurd rules

```
-keepnames class com.somepackage.yourclass
```

Comment: Or you can use this proguard rule for all fragments ```-keepnames class  * extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment```

Answer (score 13):

Since [`setCurrentScreen`](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/08/google-analytics-manual-screen-view.html) is **deprecated** you can use `firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SCREEN_VIEW, bundle)` instead.

there is a blog post [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/08/google-analytics-manual-screen-view.html) that explains more about tracking screens manually.

here is an example:

```
private fun setCurrentScreen(screenName: String) = firebaseAnalytics?.run {
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME, screenName)
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_CLASS, this@BaseFragment.javaClass.simpleName)
    logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SCREEN_VIEW, bundle)
}
```

In addition, if you want to track screens **automatically**, you can call this function in one of your `BaseFragment` lifecycle methods like `onResume`. just keep in mind that some of the fragments may not have to change the current screen, like the ones which are being created in a `ViewPager`, so I have declared an `open val` which you can `override` in order to change the default behavior.

here is the code in `BaseFragment`:

```
protected open val trackScreenView: Boolean = true

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    if (trackScreenView) setCurrentScreen(this.javaClass.simpleName)
}
```

and you can disable it by overriding it in your target `Fragment`:

```
override val trackScreenView: Boolean = false
```

By the way, if you are using [`NavigationUI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI) Component, currently there is no automatic solution for tracking screens, and it only track the single activity you have, so you can prevent firebase automatic screen reporting by putting this `meta-data` in your app manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    
    <!-- .... -->
    
    <meta-data
        android:name="google_analytics_automatic_screen_reporting_enabled"
        android:value="false" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 9):

For projects using **NavigationUI**, you can use a listener `NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener`

Inside `onCreate()`

```
override fun onCreate() {
      super.onCreate()
      .
      .
      .
      .
      navController = Navigation.findNavController(context!!, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
      navController?.addOnDestinationChangedListener(listener)
}
```

Of the 3 listener function parameters,

- `controller` is useful to obtain classname
- `destination` is useful to obtain layout xml name string of destination as found inside nav_host_fragment by the attribute `android:label`

```
private val listener = NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
      
      val bundle = Bundle()
      val currentFragmentClassName = (controller.currentDestination as FragmentNavigator.Destination).className
      bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME, destination.label.toString())
      bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_CLASS, currentFragmentClassName)
      FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(requireContext()).logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SCREEN_VIEW, bundle)
      
}
```

Don't forget cleanup

```
override fun onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy()
      navController?.removeOnDestinationChangedListener(listener)
}
```

Comment: Good approach, this is a really clean way to do it!

Comment: Clean approach, but I assume the names will be obfuscated if you use Proguard?