# How to pass "screen class" name manually from Activity/Fragment for analytics in daily user engagement

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

How to pass "**screen class**" name manually from **Activity/Fragment** for `Daily user engagement` because in past i have get all activities's screen class name in `Daily user engagement` and i'm put all data in bigquery and display our custom analytics, but now i'm replaced all activities to fragments so unable to get fragments name just got activities name.

> firebase --> analytics --> Daily user engagement window --> Class name

- Should we get fragment name in class name ?
- Should we pass fragment name manually from from fragemnt so we can get in Daily user engagement's class name

It's alrady working fine with activities but i want fragemnt name as a screen name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try using analytics [setCurrentScreen](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews) method like below

```
firebaseAnalyticsObj.setCurrentScreen(this, your_fragment.getClass().getSimpleName(), your_fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

for more check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45214101/6834114) answer