# Adding a border to Zxing QR scanner

Tags: android, kotlin, qr-code, zxing

Looking for some help with coding a border for Zxing barcode scanner in Kotlin. I've looked at some of the older threads on here and I'm not sure if the information is outdated but I'm not finding a working solution. Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance. Also I'm using it as a library so I can't modify viewfinderview directly, do I just make a custom version and make a function to draw the border?

Answer (score 0):

You might get by with using BarcodeView inside your xml and create border around that as given [here](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/EMBEDDING.md) and [sample here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937292/android-zxing-embedded-barcodeview-not-resuming). Personally I think it would be better to create your own version with using CameraX and Firebase's QR scanning library since all the control will be with you.