# Why is MLKit barcode (Qr code) scanner so slow?

Tags: android, qr-code, google-mlkit

I'm trying to implement a QR code scanner in my app using Mlkit and following these two links :

https://medium.com/codex/scan-barcodes-in-android-using-the-ml-kit-30b2a03ccd50

https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android

Mlkit and CameraX versions :

camerax_version = "1.1.0-beta03" / barcodeScanning = "17.0.2"

It works fine on any Samsung device, but on Xiaomi mi 9T pro with Android 10 it takes between 2 and 10 secondes to scan a simple QR code. On Pixel 2 with Android 11 it sometimes never work or takes up to 20 secondes to work.

When I use the following lib it works fine on every device :

[Android zxing Embedded BarcodeView not resuming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937292/android-zxing-embedded-barcodeview-not-resuming)

Why does Mlkit take so long (or don't work) to scan some simple QR code on some device ?

Thanks for the response

Comment: Can you try the ML Kit quick start app (CameraXLivePreviewActivity) to see if it's reproducible? https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart

Comment: The sample is working fine, the code is totally different that in the documentation , i will try to use the same code, thanks for your help !!

Comment: Encountered the same issue

Answer (score 1):

if you are using MLkit barcode scanning and getting process image result is slow, then use below code.it responds fast.

```
if (image.image != null && image.format == ImageFormat.YUV_420_888) {
                


                scanner.process(InputImage.fromBitmap(image.toBitmap(), image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees))
                    .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
                        if (barcodes.isNotEmpty()) {

                            if (firstCall){


                                for (barcode in barcodes) {
                                    

                                    // Handle received barcodes...


                                    Log.d("ValueXXXX ",barcode.format.toString())

                                    if (barcode.format==Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE){
                                        var data = barcode.displayValue.toString().replace("\\", "")
                                        //var json=org.json.JSONObject(data)

                                        Log.d("TAG","DATA1111 "+data)

                                        if(Utils.urlPattern.matcher(data).matches()) {
                                            firstCall=false


                                            showPopupForInvalidQRCode(R.string.DISPLAY_INVALID_QR_CODE,context)



                                            break
                                        }
                                        if (!data.isNullOrEmpty() && Utils.isJSONValid(data)){
                                            firstCall=false
                                            try {
                                                val json = JSONObject(data)
                                                Log.d("TAG","json "+json)
                                                val vibrator = context?.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
                                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
                                                        vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(300, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE))
                                                    } else {
                                                        vibrator.vibrate(300)
                                                    }

                                                 //parse your json here   

                                                break
                                            }catch (e:Exception){
                                                e.printStackTrace()
                                                showPopupForInvalidQRCode(R.string.DISPLAY_INVALID_QR_CODE,context)
                                            }
                                        }

                                        break
                                    }



                                }
                            }

                        } else {
                            // Remove bounding rect
                            barcodeBoxView.setRect(RectF())
                        }
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener {
                        firstCall=true
                        Log.d("EXCEPTION",it.message.toString())
                        //image.close()

                    }
                    

                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default camera configuration it is expected to be slow for sure because the images are too big, you need to something like

```
.setTargetResolution(Size(1200, 1600))
```

By the way, you need to check the list of supported resolutions because not any resolution will work for any phone, please check

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#SENSOR_INFO_PIXEL_ARRAY_SIZE