# Downloading multiple files using AWS Amplify for Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm building an Android app which uses [AWS Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/getting-started/q/platform/android) to list and download files from S3.

The sample code shows downloading is asynchronous:

```
Amplify.Storage.downloadFile()
    "ExampleKey",
    new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/download.txt"),
    result -> Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "Successfully downloaded: " + result.getFile().getName()),
    error -> Log.e("MyAmplifyApp",  "Download Failure", error)
);
```

I wish to download the (possibly many) files in a background thread, and notify the main thread after all files have been downloaded (or an error occurred). Questions:

What is the best way to achieve this functionality?

P.S.
I've tried the [RxAmplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/project-setup/rxjava/q/platform/android), which exposes [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) Observables on which I can call `blockingSubscribe()`. However, the bindings are very new, and I've encountered some app-crashing uncaught exceptions using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### With Vanilla Amplify

`downloadFile()` will perform its work on a background thread. Just use one of the [standard approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11125271/695787) to go back onto the main thread, from the callback:

```java
Handler handler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/download.txt");

Amplify.Storage.downloadFile(
    "ExampleKey", file,
    result -> {
        handler.post(() -> {
            Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "Successfully downloaded: " + result.getFile().getName());
        });
    },
    error -> Log.e("MyAmplifyApp",  "Download Failure", error)
);
```

#### With Rx Bindings

But personally, I would use the Rx Bindings. [The official documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/download/q/platform/android) includes snippets for the Rx API. Here's a more tailored example:

```java
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/download.txt");
RxAmplify.Storage.downloadFile("ExampleKey", file)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(result -> {
        Log.i("RxExample", "Download OK.");
    }, failure -> {
        Log.e("RxExample", "Failed.", failure);
    });
```

#### Running Many Downloads In Parallel

Build a collection of `Single`s by calling `RxAmplify.Storage.downloadFile("key", local)`. Then, use `Single.mergeArray(...)` to combine them all. Subscribe to that, in the same way as above.

```java
RxStorageCategoryBehavior storage = RxAmplify.Storage;
Single
    .mergeArray(
        storage.downloadFile("one", localOne)
            .observeResult(),
        storage.downloadFile("two", localTwo)
            .observeResult()
    )
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(/* args ... */);
```

#### Reporting Bugs

You mention that you encountered an unexpected exception. If so, please file a bug [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues/new), and I will fix it.

Comment: Thanks. Using your example as-is, I got and error for `mergeArray()`: "reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that RxProgressAwareSingleOperation<StorageDownloadFileResult> conforms to SingleSource<? extends T>". I guess I should add `observeResult()` to each `downloadFile()`?

Comment: + I wonder how I can observe both result and progress in this case...

Comment: Ah true, had to add `.observeResult()` on the calls inside the `mergeArray(...)`. Updated the post. To observe the progress as well, create a collection of the operations. Then, form an `Observable` by merging the various `.observeProgress()`.

Comment: Thanks @Jameson. How can I merge an unknown number of singles? Namely, the result of a previous `list()` operation of the bucket?

Comment: @bavaza Here's a starting place for that. You may want to create your own `Download` model that keeps the key, file, and operation all in one place. Otherwise, you can't tell which download the progress is for. https://gist.github.com/jamesonwilliams/bf66c47e46a1588daed4efa980acf7e6

Comment: Thanks. I get a build error for the `flatMapSingle`: "error: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R.flatMapSingle(item -> RxAmplify.Storage.downloadFile(item, new File(path, item)));
(argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
      RxProgressAwareSingleOperation<StorageDownloadFileResult> cannot be converted to SingleSource<? extends R>)
  where R,T are type-variables:
    R extends Object declared in method <R>flatMapSingle(Function<? super T,? extends SingleSource<? extends R>>)
    T extends Object declared in class Observable".

Comment: @bavaza oh yea use flatMap instead of flatMapSingle.