# how to change activity.runOnUiThread to viewModel thread

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-viewmodel

I have a function which accepts an activity and runs on activity UI thread, but this functions gets called from a view model, how can I convert this function run based on view model and not dependent on activity

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun onIntervalScanUpdate(over: Boolean, activity: Activity, bleStateCallback: BleStateCallback) {
        val devices: List<ScanResult> = ArrayList<ScanResult>(mDeviceMap.values)
        Collections.sort(
            devices
        ) { dev1: ScanResult, dev2: ScanResult ->
            val rssi1 = dev1.rssi
            val rssi2 = dev2.rssi
            rssi2.compareTo(rssi1)
        }
        activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable {
            mBleList.clear()
            mBleList.addAll(devices)
            if (over) {
                if(mBleList.isNotEmpty()) {
                    Timber.d("xxx device found - ${mBleList.first().device.name}")
                    mDevice = mBleList.first().device
                    connect(bleStateCallback)
                } else {
                    Timber.d("xxx device found - NONE")
                }

            }
        })
    }
```

Update:

I have changed the activity.runOnUiThred code to the following, do you think this is correct?

```
val uiHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    uiHandler.post {
        mBleList.clear()
        mBleList.addAll(devices)
        if (over) {
            if(mBleList.isNotEmpty()) {
                Timber.d("xxx device found - ${mBleList.first().device.name}")
                mDevice = mBleList.first().device
                connect(bleStateCallback)
            } else {
                Timber.d("xxx device found - NONE")
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: code which you have added is code of viewmodel Right ?

Comment: See my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11125271/769265 The code is Java, but you should get the idea. By the way, there is only 1 UI `Thread`. All activities share the same UI `Thread`, so you just need access to that.

Comment: @RujulGandhi No this is a separate file called `BlufiHelper` with this function. this function get called from view model and not activity, so I want to replace activity related thread code with view model thread

Comment: I have changed the it to        val uiHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        uiHandler.post {
            mBleList.clear()
            mBleList.addAll(devices)
            if (over) {
                if(mBleList.isNotEmpty()) {
                    Timber.d("xxx device found - ${mBleList.first().device.name}")
                    mDevice = mBleList.first().device
                    connect(bleStateCallback)
                } else {
                    Timber.d("xxx device found - NONE")
                }

            }
        }

Comment: Now where you have wrote this code ?  In ViewModel or in activity.

Comment: There's no such thing activity thread or viewmodel thread. It's either UI thread or some background thread