How to setText() TextView outside of onCreate()?
So I'm trying to do my coding homework, where i have to code an Java Android application in Android studio which manages and creates a todolist/notes for you. It should be possible to edit notes, for this function (and for creating a new note) I'm using an extra activity (notesActivity). When "Edit" is used, the notes layout should be opened with the to be edited notes details (titel,date,content) but I'm simply unable to use the setText() and updateDate() for the views. Why is that? I've provided my classes below.
package net.htlgkr.todoapp;

import static net.htlgkr.todoapp.NoteActivity.changeContent;
import static net.htlgkr.todoapp.NoteActivity.changeDate;
import static net.htlgkr.todoapp.NoteActivity.changeText;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView titleTextBox;
    DatePicker datePicker;
    TextView contentTextBox;

    public static ArrayList<Note> noteList = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView noteListView;
    NotesAdapter notesAdapter;

    boolean mainIsActive = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        noteListView = findViewById(R.id.noteListView);
        notesAdapter = new NotesAdapter(this,R.layout.list_view_layout,noteList);
        noteListView.setAdapter(notesAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(noteListView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        configActionBar();
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.action_new){
            switchToNoteActivity();
        }
        else if(id == R.id.action_save){
        }
        else if(id == android.R.id.home && !mainIsActive){
            switchToMainActivity();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private void configActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Albert Notes");
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    @Override
   public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
       super.onCreateContextMenu(menu,v,menuInfo);
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.note_menu,menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        titleTextBox = findViewById(R.id.displayTitleTextBox);
        datePicker = findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        contentTextBox = findViewById(R.id.contentTextBox);

        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo i = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == R.id.action_delete){
            noteList.remove(i.position);
            notesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }

        else if(id == R.id.action_edit){
            Note editedNote = noteList.get(i.position);
            String title = editedNote.getTitle();
            Log.d("EDITED TITLE",title);
            String content = editedNote.getContent();
            LocalDate date = editedNote.getDate();
            switchToNoteActivity();
            changeText(titleTextBox,title);
            //changeText(contentTextBox,content);
            //changeDate(date);
            return true;
        }

        else if(id == R.id.action_view){

        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void switchToMainActivity(){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
        mainIsActive = true;
    }
    public void switchToNoteActivity(){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, NoteActivity.class));
        finish();
        mainIsActive = false;
    }


}

package net.htlgkr.todoapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class NoteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static TextView titleTextBox;
    static TextView contentTextBox;
    static DatePicker datePicker;
    static NoteActivity noteActivity;
    public static ArrayList<Note> noteList = MainActivity.noteList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        titleTextBox = findViewById(R.id.displayTitleTextBox);
        contentTextBox = findViewById(R.id.contentTextBox);
        datePicker = findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        configActionBar();
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void configActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Albert Notes");
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.action_new){
            switchToNoteActivity();
        }
        else if(id == R.id.action_save){
        }
        else if(id == android.R.id.home){
            switchToMainActivity();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void saveButtonOnClick(View view){

        TextView titleTextBox = findViewById(R.id.displayTitleTextBox);
        DatePicker dateView = findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        TextView content = findViewById(R.id.contentTextBox);

        String titleString = String.valueOf(titleTextBox.getText());
        String contentString = String.valueOf(content.getText());
        int day = dateView.getDayOfMonth();
        int month = dateView.getMonth();
        int year = dateView.getYear();
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);

        Note newNote = new Note(titleString, date, contentString);
        noteList.add(newNote);
        Log.d("Eintrag getätigt", noteList.get(noteList.size()-1).getTitle());
        switchToMainActivity();
    }

    public static void changeText(TextView textView, String newText) {
        textView.setText(newText);
    }
    public static void changeContent(String newContent){
        contentTextBox.setText(newContent);
    }
    public static void changeDate(LocalDate newDate){
        datePicker.updateDate(newDate.getYear(),newDate.getMonthValue(),newDate.getDayOfMonth());
    }

    public void switchToMainActivity(){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
    public void switchToNoteActivity(){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, NoteActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}

I've already tried multiple things like different kinds of Threads, etc. but nothing seems to work

Do never modify UI elements from different threads. Instead define your code to update the element and then let it run on main thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11123621/150978

Where excactly should i implement this?

"I'm simply unable to use the setText() and updateDate() for the views." - what does it mean you're "unable to use" these methods? Why not?

Well I am able to use them but they just don't do shit, except I'm calling them from the onCreate

@Elias you cannot access non-static variables or methods in non-static methods, it's a rule. See in your code changeDate() method is a static method and you're trying to call this method inside the onContextItemSelected() method which is not static. Please try following the other approach or you can ask a specific question about the task you want to do.

You cannot access static variables or methods in non-static methods, it's a rule. See in your code changeDate() & changeText() methods are static methods and you're trying to call them inside the onContextItemSelected() method which is not a static method.
Suggestion: You can either put those two methods in the same activity MainActivity if possible and keep them non-static like this and try calling them.
 public void changeText(TextView textView, String newText) {
        textView.setText(newText);
    }
public void changeDate(LocalDate newDate){
        datePicker.updateDate(newDate.getYear(),newDate.getMonthValue(),newDate.getDayOfMonth());

    }


