# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android, multithreading, view

I have a an Activity in which I have a menu formed by three ImageView (LEFT,CENTER,RIGHT). I have two arrows (button), in order to move in the menu. When I click on the left arrow the image in the left ImageView is replaced with the image that was in the center ImageView; in a similar manner the image in the center ImageView is replaced with the image that was in the right ImageView, and for the right ImageView, a new image appears.
 When the activity is shown, I have not the required images the ImageView is shown with a default image,while the correct image is downloaded using Thread. 
After the three images are download I continue to have the three default image, and I can see the downloaded images only after movement on left or right. This, because "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." So the thred used for download, when the download is ended can touch the view of my activity.
What can I do for avoiding the problem?
Maybe I have to use handler. But I'm not able to do this.

Comment: Why are you not able to use a handler ?

Comment: I have never use it. I have to try it. Have you any suggest? May be this resolve my problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can I do for avoiding the problem?

Use `AsyncTask` instead of `Thread`, with your update-the-`ImageView` logic going in `onPostExecute()`.

Or, use a `Handler`.

Or, use `post()` on your `ImageView`.

Or, use `runOnUiThread()` on your activity.