# Android Presentation Class - How to make changes on the Presentation View dynamically

Tags: android, screen, presentation

My presentation is working finally. I have one main `activity` for my first screen and one `Presentation` for my second Screen. 
My problem is, that I can't change the content on my presentation view.

Why can't I change a `TextView` after the presentation is shown on the second screen?
Calling the method `changeText("Test123")` in the `MainActivity` crashes my app.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private PresentationActivity presentationActivity;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  


        // init Presentation Class

        DisplayManager displayManager = (DisplayManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
        Display[] presentationDisplays = displayManager.getDisplays(DisplayManager.DISPLAY_CATEGORY_PRESENTATION);
        if (presentationDisplays.length > 0) {
            // If there is more than one suitable presentation display, then we could consider
            // giving the user a choice.  For this example, we simply choose the first display
            // which is the one the system recommends as the preferred presentation display.
            Display display = presentationDisplays[0];
            PresentationActivity presentation = new PresentationActivity(this, display);
            presentation.show();

            this.presentationActivity =  presentation;    
        }
    }

    public void changeText (String s) {

        this.presentationActivity.setText(s);

    }
}



public class PresentationActivity extends Presentation {

    private TextView text;



    private PresentationActivity presentation;


public PresentationActivity(Context outerContext, Display display) {
    super(outerContext, display);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_presentation);   

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    this.text = text;
    // works fine:
    text.setText("test");      

}

public void setText(String s){

    // error
    this.text.setText(s);

}
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: Hi! I can't use LogCat because my USB port is used to connect the second screen with HDMI.

Comment: edit: ok, there are some Apps for LogCat. I will test it tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Then disconnect your MHL(?) cable after the crash, plug it into USB on your development machine, and *then* examine LogCat. Or, you might be able to get **`adb`** to work over USB, see http://tech.leolink.net/2012/11/use-adb-wifi-without-rooting-for.html. The apps you cite won't work, as you cannot view LogCat messages from other processes in an app on Android 4.1+.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I looked in the LogCat.
The exception was:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13950): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

The code in my `MainActivity` runs on another thread. To do UI work from here I need to use `runOnUiThread`. This solution I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294287/only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-views/14294323#14294323) answer.

My `changeText` methode looks like this now:

```
public void changeText (String s) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              presentationActivity.setImageView(position);
          }
    });
}
```

Thanks for the help! Now I know how to use LogCat for things like that.

Answer (score 1):

You got this issue because the context of presentation is different from that of the containing Activity:

> A Presentation is associated with the target Display at creation time
>   and configures its context and resource configuration according to the
>   display's metrics.
>
> Notably, the Context of a presentation is different from the context
>   of its containing Activity. It is important to inflate the layout of a
>   presentation and load other resources using the presentation's own
>   context to ensure that assets of the correct size and density for the
>   target display are loaded.

Hope this will justify your mentioned solution as well.