# Update ListView on UI on receiving Broadcast intent

Tags: android, user-interface, broadcastreceiver

I have a list of items on the UI. When the app catches an intent with a `BroadCastReceiver`, I need to update a specific item in the list (hide an `ImageView` on the item row). The list uses a custom adapter obviously. How can I do that?

I tried access the fragment where is the `ListView` using the `Application` object called from the receiver, but Android gave me this error:

"Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views"

Sorry if I'm a bit generic, but I don't know which part of the code provide, actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're trying to edit the list from another thread that received this Broadcast. if indeed this is the case there is a simple solution - the Activity class supplies a method called - runOnUiThread.
You can see an example on this post : [Android “Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi)

Good Luck!