# Android Image Downloader Issue

Tags: android, image, properties, bitmap

I'm trying to implement an Image downloader.

Here is the example that I used: 
http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

But unfortunately I'm getting a bunch of warnings and the result is that no image gets displayed.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jpstbcehoii2xt7/snipp2.PNG

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            final Handler uiHandler = new Handler();    
            Timer myTimer = new Timer(); // Timer erzeugen
            myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {          
                @Override           
                public void run() {                     
                             try{
                                  imageDownloader.download("http://osthessen-news.de/Media/13/03/News130308_10_DSC_2375.jpg_Thumbnail0.jpg", (ImageView) mainImage1);                   
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                                }
                             }
        }, 0L, 60L * 1000); //Intervall = 60000 Millisekunden, 0 Millisekunden bis zum ersten Start.

    }});

03-08 14:22:14.577: W/ImageDownloader(12411): Error while retrieving bitmap from http://osthessen-news.de/Media/13/03/News130308_10_DSC_2375.jpg_Thumbnail0.jpg
03-08 14:22:14.577: W/ImageDownloader(12411): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-08 14:22:14.577: W/ImageDownloader(12411):   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
03-08 14:22:14.577: W/ImageDownloader(12411):   at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
03-08 14:22:14.577: W/ImageDownloader(12411):   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
03-08 14:22:14.577: W/ImageDownloader(12411):   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
03-08 14:22:14.577: W/ImageDownloader(12411):   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
03-08 14:22:14.577: W/ImageDownloader(12411):   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-08 14:22:14.577: W/ImageDownloader(12411):   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-08 14:22:14.577: W/ImageDownloader(12411):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
03-08 14:22:14.577: W/ImageDownloader(12411):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-08 14:22:14.577: W/ImageDownloader(12411):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
```

Comment: It's better to include some part of your code as well as the _Logcat_ output as text rather than a picture.

Comment: I think the solution is to create a new Thread, but im not sure how and where :/

Comment: I think the `Image Downloader` creates an `AsyncTask` by itself so you don't need to do it. But at least add your complete `Activity` code so somebody can help you. Add your _LOGCAT_ as text to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you are getting this error is because you are trying to access a UI view from another thread rather than `Main Thread` or `Activity Thread`

Your problem has already been answered here:
[Android “Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi)

I haven't gone through that guy's tutorial but you can easily create an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and call the `ImageDownloader` in `doInBackground()` to retrieve the image first and then set your View's picture in `onPostExecute()`

I recommend to read that tutorial thoroughly cuz that guy explains everything you need. Check [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-imagedownloader/source/browse/trunk/src/com/example/android/imagedownloader/ImageListActivity.java) sample to see how he uses the `ImageDownloader` and `ImageAdapter`.

Comment: Thx, but yet, i get the old warning: 
"android.os.StrictMode&AndroidBlockGuardPolic.onNetwork(StrictM

Comment: I have checked your update. DON'T DO THAT. You are calling the `ImageDownloader` on UI thread which is terrible. I will update my answer.

Comment: The ImageDownloader itself creates an AsyncTask!

Comment: Forget about the warning for now. But you have another error in your Log. `Error while retrieving bitmap from ...`. What the hell is that? :)