# AsyncTask Socket Error

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask which connects to a network resource and tries to read data from the resource.
This resource can send data at anytime, so i need the socket to be in the background.
When i get a response on the initial connection i receive the message and it is shown on a TextView ont he MainActivity , however when the server sends another message i get 
error:

```
06-13 15:46:01.932: I/AsyncTask(1818): doInBackground: Exception Details : Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Below is my code:

```
public class Client extends AsyncTask<Void, byte[], Boolean> {

        private String SvrAddr = svradr;
        private int Svrport = port;
        private InputStream input;
        private OutputStream output;    
        private Socket nSocket;


        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params){
            boolean rslt = false;
            try{
                Log.i("AsyncTask", "doInBackground: Creating Socket");
                SocketAddress sockad = new InetSocketAddress(SvrAddr,Svrport);
                nSocket = new Socket();
                nSocket.connect(sockad,5000);
                if(nSocket.isConnected()){
                    input =  nSocket.getInputStream();
                    output = nSocket.getOutputStream();
                    Log.i("AsyncTask","doInBackground: Socket created.. Streams gotten");
                    byte[] buffer= new byte[4096];
                    int read = input.read(buffer,0,4096);
                    while(read!=-1){
                        byte[] data = new byte[read];
                        System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, data,0,read);
                        Log.i("AsyncTask","doInBackgroiund: got data :" + new String(data,"UTF-8"));
                        DisplayData(new String(data,"UTF-8"));
                        read =  input.read(buffer,0,4096);
                    }
                }
            }catch(IOException ioe){
                Log.i("AsyncTask","doInBackground: IO Exception");
                rslt=true;
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.i("AsyncTask","doInBackground: Exception Details : " + e.getMessage());
                rslt = true;
            }finally{


                try{
                    input.close();
                    output.close(); 
                    nSocket.close();
                }catch(IOException ioe){

                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.i("AsyncTask","doInBackground: Exception");
                    rslt = true;
                }
                Log.i("AsyncTask","doInBackground: Completed");
            }
            return rslt;
        }

        private void DisplayData(String msg){               
            TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            t.setText(msg);
        }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi . Did you even searched online ??

Comment: You shouldn't update from the doInBackground(). Use publishProgress and implement onProgressUpdate() to update UI from the background task. onProgressUpdate runs in  context of the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

Just move your `DisplayData(new String(data,"UTF-8"));` to OnProgressUpdate(), follow a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) if you still have problems.