# Appication stopped when displaying twitter feed with twitter4j in android

Tags: java, android, twitter4j, twitter-feed

I am working on my android project and I encounter this run-time error: Unfortunately, Example2 has stopped. All I want to do is just displaying twitter feed using twitter4j (twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar), but there is an exception on this code:

```
tweets = mTwitter.search(new Query(queryString)).getTweets();
```

I tested this out on NetBean with java application and its perfectly fine. All of the twitter is displayed and I assume there is no problem with the user authentication. I tried to follow this tutorial:
http://nosemaj.org/android-twitter

it seems works for some people but not for me :(

here is the code:

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

```
Context mContext;
Twitter mTwitter;
ListView mListView;

private static final String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "xx";
private static final String TWITTER_SECRET_KEY = "xxx";
private static final String TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN = "xx";
private static final String TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "xx";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    mTwitter = getTwitter();

}


protected  void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
     new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){

         protected Void doInBackground(Void... args){
            showTweetsAbout("happy"); 
             return null;
         }

     }.execute(); 

}
private Twitter getTwitter() {
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();     
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
    cb.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
    cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_SECRET_KEY);
    cb.setOAuthAccessToken(TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN);
    cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

    return new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
}

private void showTweetsAbout(String queryString) {
    List<Status> tweets = new ArrayList<Status>();
    ArrayList<String> tweetTexts = new ArrayList<String>();

   try {
       tweets = mTwitter.search(new Query(queryString)).getTweets()//if I comment this line, the code works fine

       // for (Status t : tweets) {
            tweetTexts.add("asdadsadasd\n\n");
        //}
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tweetTexts.add("Twitter query failed: " + e.toString());
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, tweetTexts);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.example2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.example2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>    
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

Here is the logCat

```
07-01 07:39:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(3979):     at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:8412)
07-01 07:39:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(3979):     at android.view.View.setFocusableInTouchMode(View.java:5790)
07-01 07:39:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(3979):     at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:717)
07-01 07:39:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(3979):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:463)
07-01 07:39:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(3979):     at com.example.example2.MainActivity.showTweetsAbout(MainActivity.java:94)
07-01 07:39:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(3979):     at com.example.example2.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:78)
07-01 07:39:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(3979):     at com.example.example2.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:52)
07-01 07:39:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(3979):     at com.example.example2.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-01 07:39:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(3979):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-01 07:39:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(3979):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-01 07:39:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(3979):     ... 4 more
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.focusableViewAvailable(ViewRootImpl.java:2588)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:608)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:608)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:608)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:608)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:8412)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.view.View.setFocusableInTouchMode(View.java:5790)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:717)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:463)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at com.example.example2.MainActivity.showTweetsAbout(MainActivity.java:94)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at com.example.example2.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:78)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at com.example.example2.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:52)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at com.example.example2.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-01 07:42:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     ... 4 more
```

Thank you so much for your feedback!

Comment: I don't understand the flow but is onPostExecute() called before showTweetsAbout() ? If not then your variable mTwitter is going to be null and hence cause NPE

Comment: I am not really sure about the flow. I am actually pretty new in Android. I use AsyncTask because I met an error before which is NetworkOnMainThread Exception.

Comment: Breakpoints would help, and try to see if your `mTwitter` is null before you call a method on it - that explains the whole thing

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I edited the code and there is not null exception, but now I found another problem :( it still on this part: tweets = mTwitter.search(new Query(queryString)).getTweets(). Does it have anything to do with the android version?

Comment: No, it's not a problem with Android :) I am not good at Android - but you are accessing a view by a different thread than it created. Check answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi

Comment: I got it.. I should have not accessed the UI on different thread. Thanks!