# TextView: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android

I declared my TextView and timer_count globally:

```
TextView txMp3Prog;
int timer_count=0;
```

in onCreate() i did

```
txMp3Prog = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txMp3Prog);
```

I am trying to get duration of song and set the text as follows

```
  txMp3Prog.setText("00:0"+String.valueOf(timer_count));
```

The text is set here

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          int currentPosition= 0;
            int total = mp.getDuration();
            while (mp!=null && currentPosition<total) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    currentPosition= mp.getCurrentPosition();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return;
                }        

                sbMusicProgress.setProgress(currentPosition);

                timer_count++;
                System.out.println( "Current position: "+timer_count);
                txMp3Prog.setText("00:0"+String.valueOf(timer_count));


               String  currenttext = String.valueOf(currentPosition);
                String songDuration = currenttext.substring(0, currenttext.length() / 2); 


            }
```

But when i play a song i get the error log below:

```
   07-02 11:25:36.575: E/AndroidRuntime(9418): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13294
    07-02 11:25:36.575: E/AndroidRuntime(9418): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    07-02 11:25:36.575: E/AndroidRuntime(9418):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4867)
    07-02 11:25:36.575: E/AndroidRuntime(9418):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:979)
    07-02 11:25:36.575: E/AndroidRuntime(9418):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4306)
    07-02 11:25:36.575: E/AndroidRuntime(9418):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10519)
    07-02 11:25:36.575: E/AndroidRuntime(9418):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10474)
    07-02 11:25:36.575: E/AndroidRuntime(9418):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6603)
    07-02 11:25:36.575: E/AndroidRuntime(9418):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3710)
    07-02 11:25:36.575: E/AndroidRuntime(9418):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3568)
    07-02 11:25:36.575: E/AndroidRuntime(9418):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3543)
    07-02 11:25:36.575: E/AndroidRuntime(9418):     at package.ResultatMultiple.run(ResultatMultiple.java:290)
    07-02 11:25:36.575: E/AndroidRuntime(9418):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

How can i set the text to the textview properly in run method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi)

Comment: Did you even search online ?

Comment: You can not touch UI widgets in other thread and runnable. So need to call runOnUiThread().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No other thread except the main UI thread can access or change the behavior of the UI.

You need to use this

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    MyClass.this.txMp3Prog.setText("00:0"+String.valueOf(timer_count));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

as in log:

> CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created
>   a view hierarchy can touch its views.

means you are trying to update or access UI element from non ui Thread so use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) or [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for updating Views from non UI Thread