# Visibility of ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I need to process some data when the user click the button in one activity, so the screen looks like the app stops for 2-3 seconds. It isn't a lot but I want to give the user information that everything is ok and IMO the best way will be the progressbar which is visible only when data are processed.

I found the code of ProgressBar and it looks like this:

```
    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loadingdata_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fin2_note"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

and inserted it on the middle of my layout.

And to try if the progressbar works, I put this code

`loadingimage= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingdata_progress);
        loadingimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

into `onCreate` method and everything looks fine. 
Then I recreated the code to show this progressbar only if the data is processed.

After click the user invoke this method

```
   public void fin2_clickOnFinalization(View v)
   {    

            loadingimage= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingdata_progress);
    loadingimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

          // code where data is processing
            loadingimage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       }
```

and nothing appear on the screen. I don't know where is the mistake. If I found the progress bar by id, It's strange for me that I can control it in onCreate method but in onclick method it's out of my control.

Comment: Please paste your complete xml file, in which ProgressBar is coded

Comment: I don't think the mistake was at the xml file, because when progress bar was set to visible in the onCreate everything works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your UI thread cannot show progress bar cause it is busy due to your data processing. Try to use this kind of code :

```
public void fin2_clickOnFinalization(View v) {

    new YourAsyncTask().execute();
}

private class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
        // code where data is processing
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {         
        loadingimage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loadingimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

AsyncTask let you run code in separate thread and make app more responsive, just put time-consuming code inside `doInBackground`.

Comment: Note: In the case of UI thread error when implementing this. See here solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi

Answer (score 4):

You're not giving the UI time to refresh. Your "data processing" code is running on the UI thread, blocking any visible changes. By the time the system gets control to refresh the display, you've already set it back to invisible.

To fix this, move your processing code to a separate thread or [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Then you can set the progress bar to visible, start the task, and have it turn itself invisible once it's done.

I'd recommend AsyncTask for this purpose about 90% of the time on Android, since it comes stock with useful callbacks. The developer guide for it(in the Javadoc linked above) is pretty explicit, and outlines all the steps you need to take.

Comment: thx for this post, I look for the link and it helps me to create my own class ;)

Answer (score 4):

AsyncTask is too heavily-weighted for such task.

A better much solution

```
Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        loadingimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Or even simpler (does essentially the same thing as solution above)

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        loadingimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Comment: For me this shows only after the background action has been completed?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a global ProgressDialog not in the layout but in your activity like:

```
public class MyActivity {

ProgressDialog progress = null;

protected void onCreate(...) {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Progress");
}

public void fin2_clickOnFinalization(View v)
{    
    progress.show();
    // code where data is processing
    progress.dismiss();
}

}
```

Hope i it helps

Comment: what if the user closes the activity while data is being processed ? I think creating and dismissing a dialog should be done after checking if the activity is in foreground or not otherwise it will through IllegalArgument Exception or BadTokenException if the activity is not there