# how to retrive data from socket io in listview in android

Tags: android, sockets, listview, arraylist

I am making android app using socket-io all data retrived from server through socket-io to android app and this data should format in listview. But there are problem for loading data in arrayadapter. My MainActivity.class is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView list;
String[] namesArr ;


ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    helper = new databasehelper(this);

        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.newslist);

      SocketIO socket = null;
        try {

            socket = new SocketIO("http://**************/");

            //socket = new SocketIO("http://localhost:7010/");



        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        socket.connect(new IOCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Server said:" + json.toString(2));

                 //   Log.d("json",""+json);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                System.out.println("Server said: " + data);

             //   Log.d("json",""+ data);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
                System.out.println("an Error occured");
                socketIOException.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnect() {
                System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnect() {
                System.out.println("Connection established");
            }

            @Override
            public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
                System.out.println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(JSONArray args,IOAcknowledge remoteAcknowledge) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.d("main", ""+args);

                try {
                        JSONArray object = args.getJSONArray(0);
                        Log.d("object",""+object);

                        for(int n = 0; n < object.length(); n++)
                        {
                            String ob2 = object.getString(n);
                            Log.d("ob2",""+ob2);

                            //String[] myarray = new String[n];

                            mylist.add(ob2);
                        }

                        Log.d("arraylist",""+mylist);

                        namesArr = new String[mylist.size()];
                        for (int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) {
                            namesArr[i] =  mylist.get(i);


                            Log.d("string array element",namesArr[i]);

                        }





                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }               
            }

        });

        // This line is cached until the connection is establisched.
        socket.send("Hello Server!"); 
            display(mylist);
        }   
  private void display(ArrayList<String> mylist) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String> getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mylist);

      Log.d("real Arraylist",""+mylist);

      //Log.d("array adapter",aa.toString());

     // list.setAdapter(aa);
}
   }
```

and i get error something like this

```
11-08 07:09:24.783: W/System.err(5775):     at com.mayur.socketio.IOConnection.transportMessage(IOConnection.java:703)
11-08 07:09:24.792: W/System.err(5775):     at com.mayur.socketio.WebsocketTransport.onMessage(WebsocketTransport.java:82)
11-08 07:09:24.814: W/System.err(5775):     at org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient.onWebsocketMessage(WebSocketClient.java:361)
11-08 07:09:24.814: W/System.err(5775):     at org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl.deliverMessage(WebSocketImpl.java:565)
11-08 07:09:24.823: W/System.err(5775):     at org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl.decodeFrames(WebSocketImpl.java:331)
11-08 07:09:24.823: W/System.err(5775):     at org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl.decode(WebSocketImpl.java:152)
11-08 07:09:24.823: W/System.err(5775):     at org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient.interruptableRun(WebSocketClient.java:247)
11-08 07:09:24.823: W/System.err(5775):     at org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient.run(WebSocketClient.java:193)
11-08 07:09:24.823: W/System.err(5775):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-08 07:09:24.832: W/System.err(5775): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
11-08 07:09:24.882: W/System.err(5775):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:5908)
11-08 07:09:24.882: W/System.err(5775):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:837)
11-08 07:09:24.893: W/System.err(5775):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15792)
11-08 07:09:24.893: W/System.err(5775):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15792)
11-08 07:09:24.893: W/System.err(5775):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15792)
11-08 07:09:24.904: W/System.err(5775):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15792)
11-08 07:09:24.904: W/System.err(5775):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:358)
11-08 07:09:24.913: W/System.err(5775):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15792)
11-08 07:09:24.913: W/System.err(5775):     at android.widget.AbsListView.requestLayout(AbsListView.java:1837)
11-08 07:09:24.933: W/System.err(5775):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:491)
11-08 07:09:24.933: W/System.err(5775):     at com.mayur.socketio.MainActivity$1.onMessage(MainActivity.java:147)
11-08 07:09:24.943: W/System.err(5775):     at com.mayur.socketio.IOConnection.onMessage(IOConnection.java:937)
11-08 07:09:24.943: W/System.err(5775):     at com.mayur.socketio.IOConnection.transportMessage(IOConnection.java:698)
```

Please suggest me what is problem in my code and what is solution???
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is that you set adapter in working thread. You can update views only from main thread. So replace

```
list.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

with

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       list.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the portion of the background task that updates the ui onto the main thread. There is a simple piece of code for this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {

//stuff that updates ui

    }
});
```

Reference: [Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi)

Hope this will help. :)