# Change UI crashes when called from onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I can not modify UI onPostExecute in **DialogFragment**

I have already read all questions about this. And this's not the same case. Believe me.

I know an AsyncTask doInBackground function has his own thread, and you must touch the view in onPreExecute and onPostExecute.
And with all these things, the app is still crashing.

The exception I get is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at .onPostExecute(CustomDialogFragment.java:310)     
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
```

[Can't touch views from onPostExecute's AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589673/cant-touch-views-from-onpostexecutes-asynctask)

Comment: Here: `activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { ... }`. I think `activity` is null, why don't you use `getActivity()` like below? Anyway nesting an `AsyncTask` can be dangerous, you could create memory leaks.

Comment: You don't need `runOnUiThread` as `onPostExecute` is invoked on the ui Thread

Comment: Which line is `CustomDialog.java:310`?

Comment: Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "why onPostExecute not work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: How does the link to the "Can't touch views..." question relate to this? Please supplement it with some explanation text.

Comment: why? because I can't touch views in onPostExecute in DialogFragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was much deeper than it seems.

The real problem was because I use Toast.show() and dimiss() dialog from onPostExecute.
Small time delay(100ms) solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

instead of activity.runOnUiThread use getActivity().runonUiThread

Comment: I did:

activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()

Comment: This is a off side note but is getActivity() an instance method inside activity, that you can call from inner class?

Answer (score 0):

As @Raghunandan correctly mentioned, `onPostExecute` is invoked on the UI Thread so `runOnUiThread` is not necessary.

Change your AsyncTask to get Context in its constructor:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

    private Context context;
    public DownloadFilesTask(Context context) {
            super();
            this.context = context;
    }
```

and use it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Toast.makeText(context, 
                      "why onPostExecute not work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Don't forget to instantiate the AsyncTask with the context:

```
final DownloadFilesTask downloadTask = new DownloadFilesTask(getActivity());
```

Comment: still, I can not modify UI onPostExecute in DialogFragment