# Refreshing custom List withing AsyncTask android

Tags: android, list, android-asynctask, refresh, progressdialog

I have a custom List which I want to refresh when a action bar button is clicked.
This List is within a Fragment.

I want to show a ProgressBar until the List is refreshed.

Currently Iam doing this:-

```
private class RefreshList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(refDialog!=null)
        {
            refDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        if(refDialog!=null)
        {
            refDialog =null;
        }
        refDialog =  WaitProgressFragment.newInstance();

        refDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Wait");


    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //stagAdaper.notifyDataSetChanged();

        itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



        return null;
    }

}
```

But I get this error

```
Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

How can I refresh the List while showing the progress dialog?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put

```
itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Inside `onPostExecute`.

`notifyDataSetChanged` is an UI operation and `doInBackground` does not work on UI thread, whereas `onPostExecute` does.

Comment: I tried doing it, but then the ProgressDialog does not show

Comment: You need to do something in doInBackground. If you are only testing progress dialog put a sleep in doInBackground.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the portion of the background task to the UI thread,so notify `itemsAdapter` in `onPostExecute` method as

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        if(refDialog!=null)
        {
            refDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried doing it. But then the ProgressDialog does not show

Comment: @user3146095 call           itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
 before dismissing dialog,see edited answer.