# Debug crashes in Handlers

Tags: java, android, android-webview, ads, mopub

Recently my error reporting tool started to show this crash (varies slightly depending on the manufacturer of the device due to the webviews implementation)

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4317)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChild(ViewRootImpl.java:892)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:941)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4019)
       at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:8621)
       at android.webkit.WebView.invalidate(WebView.java:1743)
       at android.webkit.WebView.viewInvalidate(WebView.java:4065)
       at android.webkit.WebView.invalidateContentRect(WebView.java:4084)
       at android.webkit.WebView.setNewPicture(WebView.java:14353)
       at android.webkit.WebView$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(WebView.java:13747)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

I think this error comes from the Mopub's implementation (or from other ads sdk mediated with mopub) since I have no webviews in my app.

How can I isolate and determinate if is an error I introduced or a bug in the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Only UIThread can handle the views (ui), so try to use this code to notify your app UI

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() { // add your code here 
}});
```

Or you can use the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

This error occur when you try to update a UI view in a background thread. Make sure you are not updating any view in your background thread like edit text, text view etc. Update your views in a UI thread. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi) for example.