# ERROR: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android, multithreading, timertask, textwatcher

I'm getting results from the server as the user types in his request.
Initially I was firing a request on each character entered.
Now, I've put a delay of 500 ms after user types in his last character & then I fire the request to fetch results from server.
I'm getting the error stated in the question on the following line, inside onSuccess():

```
search_listview.setAdapter(searchAdaptor);
```

Below is my code:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
if(!s.equals("")&&s.length()!=0){
        TextView tv_emptyView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_emptyView);
        tv_emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(frndList!=null&&frndList.size()!=0)
        frndList.removeAll(frndList);
        if(searchAdaptor!=null){
            searchAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        search_listview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pageNumber=0;

    timer.cancel();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(
            new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getListbyName(++pageNumber);
                }
            },
            DELAY
    );
}else if(s.equals("")||s.length()==0){
        TextView tv_emptyView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_emptyView);
        tv_emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        search_listview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}

private void getListbyName(int page) {
    GlobalSearchRequestHandler globalSearchRequest = new GlobalSearchRequestHandler(
            this, this, UserInfoSettings.INSTANCE.getUserId(),
            editTextSearch.getText().toString(), page + "", true,progressBar);
    globalSearchRequest.execute();
}
@Override
public void onSuccess(Object response) {

    if (response instanceof GlobalSearchBean) {
        GlobalSearchBean advSearchResultbean = (GlobalSearchBean) response;
        if (advSearchResultbean.getErrorCode().equalsIgnoreCase("000")) {
            frndList = advSearchResultbean.getUserList();
                if (frndList != null && frndList.size() > 0) {
                loading = true;
                if(searchAdaptor!=null&& pageNumber!=1){
                    searchAdaptor.updateFriendList(frndList);
                }else{
                    searchAdaptor = new SmartEntourageSearchAdaptor(this, AdvanceSearchScreenActivity.this, frndList, true);
                    search_listview.setAdapter(searchAdaptor);
                    searchAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } else{
                if (searchAdaptor != null && pageNumber != 1) {
                    loading = true;
                    searchAdaptor.updateFriendList(frndList);
                } else {
                    TextView tv_emptyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_emptyView);
                    tv_emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    search_listview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I did go through & tried answers on stackoverflow but not working.

**EDIT:**
GlobalSearchRequestHandler:

```
public class GlobalSearchRequestHandler extends JsonHttpResponseHandler {

private Context mContext;
//private Dialog mDialog;
private View progressBar;
private String encodedRequest;
private HttpCommunicationListener mHandler;
private boolean mShowProgress;
private static final String contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

public GlobalSearchRequestHandler(Context mContext,
        HttpCommunicationListener handler, String userId, String keyword,
        String pageNumber, boolean canShowProgress,View pb) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.encodedRequest = encodedRequest(userId, keyword, pageNumber);
    this.mHandler = handler;
    this.mShowProgress = canShowProgress;
    this.progressBar= pb;
}

private String encodedRequest(String userId, String keyword,
        String pageNumber) {

    JSONObject genInfoObj = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject globalSearch = new JSONObject();

    globalSearch.put("userId", userId);
    globalSearch.put("keyword", MysnlUtils.replaceSpecialCharacterEncodeRequest(keyword));
    globalSearch.put("pageNumber", pageNumber);

    genInfoObj.put("globalSearch", globalSearch);
    genInfoObj.put(getString(R.string.genInfo), MysnlUtils.getGenInfo());

    return genInfoObj.toString();
}

private String getString(int id) {
    return MysnlApplication.mAppContext.getResources().getString(id);
}

public void execute() {
    try {
        encodedRequest = "xmlrequest=" + encodedRequest;
        Logger.e(encodedRequest);
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(encodedRequest);
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore
                .getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);
        MySSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(MySSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        client.setSSLSocketFactory(sf);
        /*
         * final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 20 * 1000;
         * client.setTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
         */

        client.post(MysnlApplication.mAppContext,
                getString(R.string.php_server_url), entity, contentType,
                this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.e(e.getMessage());
        ErrorBean errorBean = new ErrorBean();
        errorBean.setErrorCode(AppConstant.BAD_REQUEST);
        errorBean.setErrorMsg(e.getMessage());
        mHandler.onFail(errorBean);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSuccess(org.json.JSONObject response) {
    Logger.e("onSuccess : "+response.toString());       

    GlobalSearchBean bean = null;
    try {
        org.json.JSONObject headJsonObject = (org.json.JSONObject) response.get("globalSearch");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        bean = gson.fromJson(headJsonObject.toString(), GlobalSearchBean.class);
        if (bean != null) {
            mHandler.onSuccess(bean);
        }
        else{
            mHandler.onFail(bean);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable error, String content) {
    Logger.e("onFailure : "+content.toString());
    ErrorBean errorBean=new ErrorBean();
    errorBean.setErrorCode(AppConstant.BAD_REQUEST);
    errorBean.setErrorMsg(content);
    mHandler.onFail(errorBean);
    try {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        /*if (mDialog != null && mDialog.isShowing()) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }*/
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    super.onFailure(error, content);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    try {
        if(mShowProgress){
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            /*mDialog = MysnlUtils.getProgressDialog(mContext);
            mDialog.show();*/
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
    try {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        /*if (mDialog != null && mDialog.isShowing()) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }*/
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    super.onFinish();
}
```

}

Comment: show your GlobalSearchRequestHandler Asynctask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi)

Comment: @Selvin I said I've tried solutions given on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
timer.cancel();
timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(
        new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getListbyName(++pageNumber);
            }
        },
        DELAY
);
```

With this:

```
search_listview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getListbyName(++pageNumber);
    }
}, DELAY);
```

Comment: This is not helping me out. Infact it is sending a request on each character entered & not waiting for 500ms.

Comment: You can store the runnable and remove it from the handler if you want. Or just use runOnUiThread with your own timer solution.

Comment: I haven't done this before. Quite clueless. But I've to resolve this issue since I've been assigned in my office.
I will be helpful if I get a price of code to solve this.