# Android “Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.” error in for loop

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to run the for loop in every half second.The loop is changing something in the view every time it is called,but the changes are made by another class i.e Speedometer.

```
Thread thread=new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            float i;
            try {

                for ( i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                            Speedometer1.onSpeedChanged(Speedometer1.getCurrentSpeed(i) + 8);
                            Speedometer2.onSpeedChanged(Speedometer2.getCurrentSpeed(i) + 8);
                            Speedometer3.onSpeedChanged(Speedometer3.getCurrentSpeed(i) + 8);
                            Speedometer4.onSpeedChanged(Speedometer4.getCurrentSpeed(i) + 8);
                            Speedometer5.onSpeedChanged(Speedometer5.getCurrentSpeed(i) + 8);
                            Speedometer6.onSpeedChanged(Speedometer6.getCurrentSpeed(i) + 8);


                    sleep(500);
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    };thread.start();
```

Comment: refer [Android “Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's because any view can be only modify in the main thread or ui Thread. Try running `onSpeedChanged()` using `runOnUiThread()`. Like this:

```
    Thread thread=new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        float i;
        try {

            for ( i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Speedometer1.onSpeedChanged(Speedometer1.getCurrentSpeed(i) + 8);
                        Speedometer2.onSpeedChanged(Speedometer2.getCurrentSpeed(i) + 8);
                        Speedometer3.onSpeedChanged(Speedometer3.getCurrentSpeed(i) + 8);
                        Speedometer4.onSpeedChanged(Speedometer4.getCurrentSpeed(i) + 8);
                        Speedometer5.onSpeedChanged(Speedometer5.getCurrentSpeed(i) + 8);
                        Speedometer6.onSpeedChanged(Speedometer6.getCurrentSpeed(i) + 8)

                    }

                });


                sleep(500);
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
};thread.start();
```

Comment: Running perfectly... Thanks alot

Answer (score 13):

You should update the UI Components in `runOnUIThread`.Sample code is

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {

       //stuff that updates ui

    }
});
```

Comment: thanks so much, it worked!

Answer (score 10):

You should update your UI on the UI thread.

For that, create a handler in your onCreate() method:

```
private Handler mHandler;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mHandler = new Handler();
    // ...
}
```

Then call the handler in your separate thread to execute it on the main thread:

```
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Update your UI
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify `View` objects from outside the main thread. Even though your `Speedometer` class is making the changes, it is running in the secondary thread you have created.

You could create a `Runnable` and post with deejay to a `Handler` created by the main thread, or use other similar techniques to accomplish the same.