# javafx android FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON

Tags: android, gluon, javafxports

In my app, I need to make sure the android device's screen stays on when the user clicks a button. When the use clicks another button, I want to allow the screen to turn off when it normally would. To do this, I need to call:
`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`

The android documentation states that this call must be made from an activity, which is what I've done. Here is my code snippet:

```
public class AndroidDataProvider implements DataProvider {
    @Override
    public void keepScreenOn(boolean flag) {
        if(flag) {
            Window window = FXActivity.getInstance().getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }
        else {
            Window window = FXActivity.getInstance().getWindow();
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code on my Samsung Galaxy S5 and S6, I get an exception. 
The code to keep the screen on works when I run it natively in android studio, so that's not the issue. Any idea how to get this functionality to work?  wake lock will not work because I need to enable and disable this functionality based on UI events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the exception (`./adb logcat -v threadtime`):

```
AndroidRuntime: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6855)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1040)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19657)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.setLayoutParams(View.java:13247)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.updateViewLayout(WindowManagerGlobal.java:365)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.updateViewLayout(WindowManagerImpl.java:99)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.onWindowAttributesChanged(Activity.java:2867)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Window.dispatchWindowAttributesChanged(Window.java:1098)
AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.dispatchWindowAttributesChanged(PhoneWindow.java:2998)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Window.setFlags(Window.java:1075)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Window.addFlags(Window.java:1033)
```

the message `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views` will give you enough information. If you check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi), you just need to move your code to the main thread:

```
    FXActivity.getInstance().runOnUiThread(() -> {
        Window window = FXActivity.getInstance().getWindow();
        if (flag) {
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        } else {
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Jose.  The code worked except that I had to replace the lambda with the old style method.

Comment: That shouldn't be required... as Retrolambda is applied to the Android package as well