# Android - how to update activity view from fragment contained in the activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, view

***Concise***: I am looking for a way to update a view in an activity from a fragment that the activity contains.

***In detail***: I have a fragment and an activity that contains the fragment. The activity has a navigation drawer and the navigation drawer contains a image view. What I am trying is to update the image view in the navigation drawer when a HTTP GET request returns a response from the fragment; the response contains a URL to where an image loader parses an image for the image view in the navigation drawer.

*Given this, I am trying to get an instance of the view in the activity from the fragment, but I am not sure how to do so. Even, I am not sure if I am on the right direction...*

I will greatly appreciate any input.

Regards,

Comment: You can do  this thing in your `FragmentDrawer` class. if you have. like one [HERE](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create Interface:

```
public interface mInterface{

  public void updateIMG(String url);

}
```

Implement this interface inside your activity and Override `updateIMG()` method.

Inside your fragment what ever you need to call `updateIMG()` just initiate interface and call a method.

```
mInterface listener =  (mInterface)getActivity();
listener.updateIMG(url);
```

Then you call  this interface method it will  run code inside overrided method inside activity.

---

In case you get *Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.*, [try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi).

Comment: `mInterface listener =  (mInterface)getActivity();` This line always gives me error `MainActivity cannot be cast to HomeFragment$OnMessageUpdateListener`. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Declare view as public which you want to update and then you can access that view from the fragment and can update from there

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LocalBroadCast` to send a broadcast from `Fragment` whenever needed and then receive the broadcast in `Activity` and do the changes.

You can also implement `Activity`, `Fragment` communication through an `interface`. Refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)  to implement the same.