# Why occur only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views on android?

Tags: android

I know 
if I want to use a thread in UI group, must use a handler.
because, android UI is single thread model.
so, If another thread accesses the UI, 
occur

`android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

so I use handler
but same occur error message.

```
private static TextView sTextView; //global variable
public void showText(final TextView textView) {
   sTextView = textView;
   sTextView.findViewById(R.id.text);
   Looper.prepare();

   final Handler handler = new Handler();
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
        public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       sTextView.setText("123123123");
                    }
                });
        }
      }).start();
      Looper.loop();
    }
```

and showText called

```
private VideoCapture videoCapture; //global variable
private TextView mText;  //global variable

public void beginCapture() {
   videoCapture.showText(mText);
}
```

and I build. but occur error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi)

Answer (score 0):

It should be the UI thread, not any random thread.

For fragment:

```
((Activity)mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sTextView.setText("123123123");
            }
        });
```

For Activity:

```
MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sTextView.setText("123123123");
            }
        });
```

Thats it, you don't need any `Handlers` or `Loopers` or `Threads` just the above lines of code.