# Why editing LayoutParams size doesn't have the effect of a canvas size

Tags: android, canvas, layoutparams

I am working on slide menu view which extends SurfaceView but when I try to change size of the view a canvas does not change.

For debug purpose, I am changing size of the view calling method:

```
public void changeSize() {
    width += 10;
    getLayoutParams().width = width;
    this.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
}
```

Then in a draw function I paint the canvas white and draw red line diagonally across the view:

```
public void draw() throws Exception {
  SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = getHolder();
  if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
    Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
    Log.i(TAG, "draw > canvas size: " + canvas.getWidth() + " " + canvas.getHeight() );
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
    canvas.drawLine(0, getLayoutParams().height, getLayoutParams().width, 0, paint);

    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
  }
}
```

What I see is a white rectangle with fixed size and part of red line:
[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNOr6.png).

Also, when I call `this.getWidth()` I get unchanged width.
Why view size is not changing? Is it the same reason that the canvas is not changing? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found reason for myself.

I did not mention about something - that I thought was not important - I called `changeSize()` via other thread than created the view and this is not allowed because: `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views`. And this problem was many time solved, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi)

I could use [`Activity.runOnUiThread()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) method but I did not want to pass the `Activity` to the view so I use [View.post()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)) method in the `changeSize()` like this:

```
Runnable changeParams = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    getLayoutParams().width = width;
    setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
  }
};
this.post(changeParams);
```

**Update:**

Maybe I do not know about proper way of using the UI Thread but whatever I tried I can not change view parameters smoothly.

Some workarounds to implement a slide menu:

1. Do [Android navigation Drawer][4] -- you can custiomize it with restictions e.g. you can not do the navigation drawer moving from top.
2. Use [Android animations][5] -- with it you can move or scale a view but can not resizing it.

*I can not put more than 2 links with my reputation:*

(4): developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

(5): developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html

Answer (score 0):

By doing `getLayoutParams().width = width;` you are changing layout params of the `View`. But you are performing drawing on a `Canvas` that owns `SurfaceHolder`, and not the one an ordinary `View` will provide you.

So, in order to change the size of the `SurfaceView`, you have to interact with `SurfaceHolder`:

```
surfaceView.getHolder().setFixedSize(width, height);
```

Comment: I tried it before in two places: 1) in `changeSize()` after `setLayoutParams(...)`, and 2) in `draw()` method. Both do not work as same as [setSizeFromLayout()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#setSizeFromLayout()) which could provide same size like layout.

Comment: `SurfaceHolder` will be accessible as soon as [SurfaceHolder#Callback#surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html) is fired. Have you tried from there?