# Android: only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views when calling invalidate()

Tags: android, invalidation

I'm trying to play a gif using the `Movie` object and it requires me to call the `invalidate()` method. However whenever I call this method I get the following error:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

How do I fix this and why is it happening

Comment: post your code snippet

Comment: run the code snippet in UI thread which is causing issue.use runOnUiThread method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Runs the specified action on the UI thread.

I would like to recommend read this site [runOnUiThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

```java
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // call the invalidate()
  }
});
```

Comment: After passing the Activity through one or two classes this worked, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
 final Handler handler=new Handler();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           //your code
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    invalidate()
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 3):

in case you need it in Kotlin:

```
val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    handler.post({
        invalidate()
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

In Android, only the Main thread (also called the UI thread) can update views. This is because in Android the UI toolkit s not thread safe.

When you try to update the UI from a worker thread Android throws this exception.

Make sure to update the UI from the Main thread.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question and the answers here already work but I had an issue with just using `Handler` because by default android studio uses the wrong `Handler` object. I had to specify `android.os.Handler` ie:

```
final android.os.Handler handler=new android.os.Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            do_your_ui_stuff_here
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a method in the Android SDK you can use to run invalidate() on the UI thread without having to make your own runnable or handler manually, see the official docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate()).

> `public void postInvalidate ()`
>
> Cause an invalidate to happen on a subsequent cycle through the event loop. Use this to invalidate the View from a non-UI thread.
>
> This method can be invoked from outside of the UI thread only when this View is attached to a window.