# Why is no exception thrown when operating UI in a background thread in previous versions?

Tags: android, multithreading

We released an android APP several years ago, and there's a View.setVisibility() method used in a sub thread. 
It has been no problem in these years until Android O Developer Preview 4.
When I test our APP on Android O Developer Preview 4, I found View.setVisibility() in a sub thread will throw a exception as follows:

**android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**

I've moved this method to main thread and fixed this problem.

But my questions are:

1. Why is no exception thrown in previous versions(even no exception in Android O Developer Preview 1)?
2. What change in Android O leads to this problem? We should explain it to our customer but we can't find the proof on Android developer's website.

Answer (score 2):

This exception [was thrown in previous versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi).  It's just never been thrown *reliably*.  Regardless, it's always been wrong to access UI elements from a background thread.  Your code is not thread safe, and it's possible that it has always exhibited subtle bugs that have gone unreported.  You should fix your code.