# Program strangely skipping a piece of code in Xamarin Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, runtime-error

Today while programming my app,I suddenly came across a strange behavior. I was creating a backspace button for my app but the compiler was just skipping a piece of code.
Here is the layout of my main.axml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<EditText
    android:text="123456123456123456"
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
<TextView
    android:text="Text"
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:background="#555555"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
<Button
    android:text="Backspace"
    android:id="@+id/bksp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#555555"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my MainActivity.cs content

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using System.Timers;

namespace App2
{
[Activity(Label = "App2", MainLauncher = true, WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.StateAlwaysHidden)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private bool Bksp_isdown = false;
    private int intt = 0;
    private Timer Bksp_tmr;
    private Button Bksp;
    private EditText Inputt;
    private TextView Resultt;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        this.Bksp_tmr = new Timer(500);
        this.Bksp = this.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.bksp);
        this.Inputt = this.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.input);
        this.Resultt = this.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.result);
        this.Inputt.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;
        this.Bksp.Touch += this.B_backspace_Touch;
        this.Bksp_tmr.Elapsed += this.Bksp_tmr_Elapsed;
    }

    private void Bksp_tmr_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Resultt.Text = "worked" 
                        + this.Bksp_isdown.ToString() + this.Inputt.SelectionStart.ToString();
        while (true)
        {
            this.intt = this.intt + 100;
            this.Backspace();
        }
    }

    private void B_backspace_Touch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Bksp_isdown = true;
        if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
        {
            this.Backspace();
            this.Bksp_tmr.Start();
        }
        else if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
        {
            this.Bksp_tmr.Stop();
            this.Bksp_isdown = false;
        }
    }
    private bool Backspace()
    {
        intt++;
        this.Bksp.Text = intt.ToString();
        if (this.Inputt.SelectionStart == 0)
            return false;

        string str = this.Inputt.Text;
        int sel = this.Inputt.SelectionStart;
        str = str.Substring(0, sel - 1) + str.Substring(sel);
        this.Inputt.Text = str;
        this.Inputt.SetSelection(sel - 1);
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

When I deployed and run this code in an Android 6 device, I saw a strange behavior. 
There is a method above named Bksp_tmr_Elapsed which ran in the program partially that the while(true) and the code inside it was fully ignored. I haven't seen such behavior in my entire life.
You may ask why I have given a constant Boolean expression in while loop. This was only because the code was not running normally as I can expect an infinite loop till crash of the application, but unfortunately not. Please help!!

**Update:** I checked the code and got a note that only the first line inside Bksp_tmr_Elapsed method executed in the app. I made some changes to the code of which I am providing the screenshot.

[Check here the first two lines in the method Bksp_tmr_Elapsed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YGFT.jpg)

[Check here the updated code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgZm8.jpg)

Now we can make a conclusion that obviously the app in the device is the updated one and simply ignoring all other lines of the method. Seems like a hidden return statement the compiler is adding to the second line of the method which I am unaware of or whatsoever I don't know. Please explain this!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

==Edit==

i added a try catch to your peace of code as seen below and found the problem

```
  private void Bksp_tmr_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            this.Resultt.Text = "worked"
                            + this.Bksp_isdown.ToString() + this.Inputt.SelectionStart.ToString();
            while (true)
            {
                this.intt = this.intt + 100;
                this.Backspace();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long);
        }
    }
```

the error i got was as follows

> {Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()

To read about this error more have a look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5162096/3578728)

To fix this do the following (add threading to your project)

```
 RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {

                this.Resultt.Text = "worked"
                                + this.Bksp_isdown.ToString() + this.Inputt.SelectionStart.ToString();
                while (true)
                {
                    this.intt = this.intt + 100;
                    this.Backspace();
                }
            });
```

You can read up on RunOnUiThread [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but no, the problem was not false deployment. I have updated the question.

Comment: Ill have a look at if i can reproduce this ill be back momentarily

Comment: i have found the problem can't believe i didn't think of this sooner
i added a try catch on your code and found this error 
{Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.