# A simple clock for an android game?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to implement a simple game with Android sdk. This game uses a custom view as the game area. I tried to use this code snippet to add a simple clock to the game. Basically it launches a thread which calls `invalidate` on the custom game view with a fixed frequency:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    class GameClock extends Thread {

        CanvasView cv;

        public GameClock(Activity ctx) {
            cv = ctx.findViewById(R.id.MainGame);
        }

        public void run() {
            while (! cv.initialized) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                }
            }

            // TODO: fix this
            while (true) {
                cv.invalidate();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    new GameClock(this).run();

}
```

But when I launch the app, it just hangs and doesn't display anything. Why does this happen? How can I fix it to work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

By executing `new GameClock(this).run();`, you just execute the `run` method in current thread, you need call `new GameClock(this).start();` to start a new thread.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I corrected that and now the app crashes with this error:         
 `08-28 21:58:44.518 3675-3695/com.example.saga.rotatingcircle E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-33681
    Process: com.example.saga.rotatingcircle, PID: 3675
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.` Is it not possible to call `invalidate` on a view from another thread?

Comment: @saga This helps  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi