# why fun not executed inside Thread kotlin?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin

- I try execute function inside Thread but that function not executed:

  ```
  Thread {
      run {
          Thread.sleep(1000)
          createView(view, inflater)
      }
  }.start()
  ```
- So i try with another code like:

  ```
  thread(start = true) {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      createView(view, inflater)
  }
  ```

  and again the createView not executed
- Finally I try:

  ```
  Thread {
      Thread.sleep(5000)
      fun run() {
          Runnable {
              createView(view, inflater)
          }
      }
  }.start()
  ```

  and i got an error:

  > "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the Main Thread can alter views. So you would need to do something like this:

```
Thread {
    Thread.sleep(5000)

    this@SomeActivity.runOnUiThread(Runnable {
        createView(view, inflater)
    })
}.start()
```