# Pyjnius - 'Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.' error when attempting to access android.view.Window methods

Tags: java, android, python, kivy, pyjnius

I've spent the past three hours struggling to find a solution. Other answers mention the reason for such is because the code is being executed in a separate thread, which makes sense, but as someone who doesn't know Java, combined with very little documentation for `pyjnius`, I have no idea how to translate the class outlined here to `pyjnius': [Android "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from jnius import autoclass

CurrentActivity  = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity
view = CurrentActivity.getWindow().getDecorView()
view.setKeepScreenOn(True)

class Root(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class SomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()

SomeApp().run()
```

The same error occurs when using a different method of android.view.Window:

```
CurrentActivity  = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity
WindowManager = autoclass('android.view.WindowManager$LayoutParams')
CurrentActivity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
```

output of `adb logcat python`:

```
12-15 16:48:21.692 18623 18646 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
12-15 16:48:21.692 18623 18646 I python  : WARNING:kivy:stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
12-15 16:48:21.693 18623 18646 I python  :    File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
12-15 16:48:21.693 18623 18646 I python  : WARNING:kivy:stderr:   File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
12-15 16:48:21.694 18623 18646 I python  :      view.setKeepScreenOn(True)
12-15 16:48:21.694 18623 18646 I python  : WARNING:kivy:stderr:     view.setKeepScreenOn(True)
12-15 16:48:21.695 18623 18646 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 734, in jnius.JavaMethod.__call__ (jnius/jnius.c:25894)
12-15 16:48:21.695 18623 18646 I python  : WARNING:kivy:stderr:   File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 734, in jnius.JavaMethod.__call__ (jnius/jnius.c:25894)
12-15 16:48:21.697 18623 18646 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 828, in jnius.JavaMethod.call_method (jnius/jnius.c:27082)
12-15 16:48:21.697 18623 18646 I python  : WARNING:kivy:stderr:   File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 828, in jnius.JavaMethod.call_method (jnius/jnius.c:27082)
12-15 16:48:21.698 18623 18646 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_utils.pxi", line 93, in jnius.check_exception (jnius/jnius.c:4012)
12-15 16:48:21.698 18623 18646 I python  : WARNING:kivy:stderr:   File "jnius/jnius_utils.pxi", line 93, in jnius.check_exception (jnius/jnius.c:4012)
12-15 16:48:21.699 18623 18646 I python  :  jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
12-15 16:48:21.699 18623 18646 I python  : WARNING:kivy:stderr: jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
12-15 16:48:21.822 18623 18646 I python  : Python for android ended.
12-15 16:48:21.830 18623 18623 V SDL     : onWindowFocusChanged(): false
12-15 16:48:21.833 18623 18623 V PythonActivity: onPause()
12-15 16:48:21.833 18623 18623 V SDL     : onPause()
12-15 16:48:21.833 18623 18623 V SDL     : nativePause()
12-15 16:48:21.833 18623 18623 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 18623 (ample.myaasdqpp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like the following (not tested):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from jnius import autoclass
from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread


class Root(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class SomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.do_window_stuff()
        return Root()

    @run_on_ui_thread
    def do_window_stuff(self):
        CurrentActivity  = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity
        view = CurrentActivity.getWindow().getDecorView()
        view.setKeepScreenOn(True)

SomeApp().run()
```

If you just want to set this permanently for your app, you can also enable wakelock via buildozer.spec or the `--wakelock` p4a argument.