# Android getting Only the original thread that created error with useing listerner again

Tags: android

In simple part of my application i connect to internet to getting data from server, for managing original thread i use simple interface as listener to send data after fetch from server to main thread, but i get this error again:

```
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views
```

**my listener:**

```
public void getProductData(OnGettingProducts listener) {
    onGettingProducts = listener;
}

public interface OnGettingProducts {
    void onProducts(String data);
}
```

**my thread:**

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        String parseUrl = ".....";

        String data = getJSON(parseUrl);
        if (onGettingProducts != null) {
            onGettingProducts.onProducts(data);
        }
    }
}.start();
```

listener on main thread as `All_Products` fragment:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    getProductData(new OnGettingProducts() {
        @Override
        public void onProducts(String data) {
            Gson converter = new Gson();

            Type type = new TypeToken<List<ProductDetails>>() {
            }.getType();
            List<ProductDetails> list = converter.fromJson(data, type);

            addProducts(list);
        }
    });

    return mView;
}
```

**and `addProducts` method to update adapter:**

```
private void addProducts(List<ProductDetails> products) {
    if (products.size() > 0) {
        productsList.addAll(products);

        for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
            if (products.get(i).getStatus() != null && !"publish".equalsIgnoreCase(products.get(i).getStatus())) {
                for (int j = 0; j < productsList.size(); j++) {
                    if (products.get(i).getId() == productsList.get(j).getId()) {
                        productsList.remove(j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Logcat:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7905)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1276)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22139)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22139)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22139)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22139)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22139)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22139)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22139)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.requestLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1303)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22139)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22139)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22139)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22139)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22139)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22139)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:360)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:22139)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.requestLayout(RecyclerView.java:4202)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecyclerViewDataObserver.onChanged(RecyclerView.java:5286)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$AdapterDataObservable.notifyChanged(RecyclerView.java:11997)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(RecyclerView.java:7070)
    at com.vectorcoder.androidwoocommerce.fragments.All_Products.addProducts(All_Products.java:423)
    at com.vectorcoder.androidwoocommerce.fragments.All_Products.access$000(All_Products.java:69)
    at com.vectorcoder.androidwoocommerce.fragments.All_Products$1.onProducts(All_Products.java:157)
    at com.vectorcoder.androidwoocommerce.fragments.All_Products$10.run(All_Products.java:617)
```

Comment: Please provide stack trace for better understanding

Comment: @UmaSankar post updated

Comment: have a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/5162096/6945674

Comment: I can clearly see the issue here which is you are calling `onGettingProducts.onProducts(data);` from different thread. If you post it to main thread, your problem will be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onGettingProducts.onProducts(data);` is being called from non UI thread thus application shows this exception. You need to call it from UI thread so it can interact with views in UI.

You can use `runOnUiThread()` to run your listener on UI thread.

```
try {
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        onGettingProducts.onProducts(data);
    }
});
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```