# Access function of another class from other class fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to access function of a class to my fragment in another class, but got this following error

```
07-08 15:22:34.286 13344-13952/com.img.gosuperleauge E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-37
Process: com.img.gosuperleauge, PID: 13344
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6915)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19686)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4295)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4237)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4210)
    at com.andrognito.flashbar.FlashbarContainerView.show$flashbar_release(FlashbarContainerView.kt:141)
    at com.andrognito.flashbar.Flashbar.show(Flashbar.kt:31)
    at com.img.gosuperleauge.Extras.AppUtils$Companion.showError(AppUtils.kt:167)
    at com.img.gosuperleauge.Fragment.PanValidationFragment$VerifyPanDetails$strRequest$1.parseNetworkError(PanValidationFragment.kt:581)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.parseAndDeliverNetworkError(NetworkDispatcher.java:171)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:159)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
```

below is the code in my first class

```
Flashbar.Builder(context)
                .gravity(Flashbar.Gravity.TOP)
                .duration(5000)
                .title("Error!!")
                .message(mesg)
                .icon(R.drawable.logo)
                .backgroundDrawable(R.drawable.error_bg)
                .titleColorRes(R.color.white)
                .messageColorRes(R.color.white)
                .enterAnimation(FlashAnim.with(context)
                        .animateBar()
                        .duration(750)
                        .alpha()
                        .overshoot())
                .exitAnimation(FlashAnim.with(context)
                        .animateBar()
                        .duration(400)
                        .accelerateDecelerate())
                .build()
```

below is how i am calling above in my fragment

```
 AppUtils.showError_c(context as VerifyAccountActivity,obj.getString("message"))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi

Comment: Can't solve my problem with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your code that updates the UI in the UI thread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    //put your code here   
    }
});
```

Comment: Problem is still same

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I think you are using the application context in that syntax. In this kind of library, you have to use the context of the activity's context. like getActivity() in fragment and Mainactivity.this in the activity.

Comment: I have tried to used getActivity() also, but problem is still same.

Comment: main issue is with, 'context as VerifyAccountActivity'  as i guess

Comment: have you try passing activty?\