# Thread management Mutex vs Synchronized

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, global-scope

I have couple of options:

**A**:

```
   GlobalScope.launch {
        countTo("A",5)
    }
    GlobalScope.launch {
        countTo("B",5)
    }

    
   private fun countTo(from:String, k: Int) {
        for (i in 0 until k) {
            RLog.d("From:$from: $i")
            Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
}
```

Output:

```
From:A: 0
From:B: 1
From:A: 1
From:B: 2
From:A: 2
From:B: 3
From:A: 3
From:B: 4
From:A: 4
```

**B**:

```
   GlobalScope.launch {
        countTo("A",5)
    }
    GlobalScope.launch {
        countTo("B",5)
    }

   private val lock = Mutex()
   private suspend fun countTo(from:String, k: Int) {
    lock.withLock {
        for (i in 0 until k) {
            RLog.d("From:$from: $i")
            Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
From:A: 0
From:A: 1
From:A: 2
From:A: 3
From:A: 4
From:B: 0
From:B: 1
From:B: 2
From:B: 3
From:B: 4
```

**C**:

```
    GlobalScope.launch {
        countTo("A",5)
    }
    GlobalScope.launch {
        countTo("B",5)
    }

    @Synchronized
    private fun countTo(from:String, k: Int) {
        for (i in 0 until k) {
            RLog.d("From:$from: $i")
            Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
     }
```

Output:

```
From:A: 0
From:A: 1
From:A: 2
From:A: 3
From:A: 4
From:B: 0
From:B: 1
From:B: 2
From:B: 3
From:B: 4
```

**D**:

```
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        countTo("A",5)
    }
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        countTo("B",5)
    }

    private fun countTo(from:String, k: Int) {
        for (i in 0 until k) {
            RLog.d("From:$from: $i")
            Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
From:A: 0
From:A: 1
From:A: 2
From:A: 3
From:A: 4
From:B: 0
From:B: 1
From:B: 2
From:B: 3
From:B: 4
```

My questions is:

1. What causes A and D act differently? Does GlobalScope have more threads and lifecycleScope have single thread?
2. B,C,D acts the same way, but my assumption of Mutex was it block access to thread and never calls the function. So synchronized can run it in sync way. So what mutex different from synchronized?
3. Does lifecycleScope acts same as synchronized in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers to your question is :-

1. `lifecycleScope.launch` does not run the code in separate thread it will use the `Main` Dispatcher by default, If you want it run in separate thread you can pass a Dispatcher like `lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)` On Other hand `GlobalScope` will by default use `Dispatchers.Default` . You can check this just printing the Thread name inside `launch`.
2. In this case `Mutex` and `@Synchronized` is same because you are holding the mutext throughout the execution it will only get released once the thread done running its code. `@Synchronized` will make the method itself `synchronized` which will act the same.
3. `lifecycleScope` is just a scope it has nothing to do with `synchronized` .

These are the less narrative answers to your question i hope its making sense.  You can check these behaviors by just printing the Thread name in Log inside `launch`.
Please check [This nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65047468/4168607) for a deeper understanding.