# Is there a difference between using GlobalScope.launch and CoroutineScope().launch to launch a coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope, structured-concurrency

There are different ways of launching a coroutine in Kotlin. I found a couple of examples where [`GlobalScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/) and [`CoroutineScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope.html?query=fun%20CoroutineScope(context:%20CoroutineContext):%20CoroutineScope) are used. But the latter one is being created directly when launching a coroutine:

1. Using `GlobalScope`:

   ```
   fun loadConfiguration() {
       GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
          val config = fetchConfigFromServer() // network request
          updateConfiguration(config)
       }
   }
   ```
2. Using `CoroutineScope` instances, created directly when launching a coroutine:

   ```
   fun loadConfiguration() {
       CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
           val config = fetchConfigFromServer() // network request
           updateConfiguration(config)
       }
   }
   ```

In this case is there a difference between these two approaches?

Doesn't the second case violate the **[principle of structured concurrency](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#structured-concurrency)**?

Comment: have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65008486/globalscope-vs-coroutinescope-vs-lifecyclescope/65047468#65047468?

Comment: @ADM, thanks for the link, it seems this is it.

Comment: Yes, the second one is an anti-pattern. There's no reason to create a new scope if you aren't going to store a reference to it or manage its lifecycle. And using GlobalScope in some cases is a code smell, at least often enough that it now shows a compiler warning by default if you use it at all. I think they created a monster of newbies overusing it since they use it in all their basic examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Doesn't the second case violate the principle of structured concurrency?

Actually both cases violate it equally, because they have pretty much the exact same semantics. All the warnings against using `GlobalScope.launch` that you may have encountered, apply to `CoroutineScope().launch` just the same. A slight difference is that the latter is entirely pointless, whereas the former at least has *some* legitimate use cases.

Writing `CoroutineScope().launch` instead of `GlobalScope.launch` obscures the intent and consequences, as well as creates a needless object every time.

I think the `CoroutineScope().launch` idiom came into being solely because it circumvented the warnings you get for `GlobalScope.launch`.