# Kotlin adapter Required: Int Found: String?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have API data which ID's are `uuid` (strings) and not (integer) and when I want to get those ids in my adapter it says

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Int
Found:
String?
```

`Sample of API items`

```
{
    "id":"0ade1bfb-6d02-4a1f-9cd4-dc88fa8aadbd",
    "name":"ABC",
    "photo":null // if not null, will be full URL of image (https://example.com/img/abc.jpg)
}
```

#### Code

`Adapter (commented)`

```
class ServicesAdapter(private val serviceList: List<Service>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ServicesAdapter.ServiceViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ServiceViewHolder {
        val imageView =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.service_item, parent, false)

        return ServiceViewHolder(imageView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ServiceViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = serviceList[position]

        holder.imageView.setImageResource(currentItem.photo) <-- error line
        holder.textView.text = currentItem.name
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = serviceList.size

    class ServiceViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val imageView: ImageView = itemView.imageView
        val textView: TextView = itemView.textView2
    }
}
```

`Activity`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    run("api_url")
}

fun run(url: String) {
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .build()

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {}
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val list: ArrayList<Service> = ArrayList()
            getServices(response.body()!!.string(), list)

            recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            recycler.adapter = ServicesAdapter(list)
        }
    })
}

fun getServices(response: String, list: ArrayList<Service>) {
    var jsonObject = JSONObject(response)
    val jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data")

    for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
        val jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
        var listingObject = Service(
            jsonObject1.getString("id"),
            jsonObject1.getString("name"),
            jsonObject1.getString("photo")
        )
        list.add(listingObject)
    }
}
```

`Class`

```
class Service (val id: String?, val name: String?, val photo: String?) {
}
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines of code in your `OnBindViewHolder` to load images from the URL

```
       currentItem.photo?.apply{
        Glide.with(holder.imageView.context)
        .load(this)
        .into(holder.imageView)
   }
```

Comment: I am getting this error now `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.` which is comming from this line of my activity file `recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)`

Comment: @mafortis try moving `recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)` out of the thread. Add it in the XML itself or after `setContentView`

Comment: I've moved it to `onCreate` error is the same

Comment: well as a last resort, add it in xml

Comment: sorry I'm newbie, how?

Comment: `app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"` add this attribute in your `RecyclerView`

Comment: not 100% sure but I guess it's related to `recycler.` because when I moved it to `onCreate` error was the same but this time pointed to `recycler.adapter = ServicesAdapter(list)` (same goes when I added it to xml)

Comment: check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi

Comment: didn't understand it :/

Comment: I added this recycler to my MainActivity file do we have more `main thread` in there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227638/discussion-between-rcs-and-mafortis).

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.imageView.setImageResource(currentItem.photo)
```

this method requires int value, which you are providing null(treated as null string)

try replacing null as blank while parsing json data

or you can use this

```
public static boolean isBlankOrNull(String value)
{
    return (value == null || value.equals("") || value.equals("null") || value.trim().equals(""));
}
```

like this

```
holder.imageView.setImageResource(isBlankOrNull(currentItem.photo) ? 0 : currentItem.photo)
```

Comment: `try replacing null as blank while parsing json data` How? If I knew that I wouldn't ask :/ (you mean from backend? that is impossible because I'm not in charge of that server)

Comment: @mafortis use `Glide` to load the images

Comment: I have `Glide` installed how should I change my code?

Comment: holder.imageView.setImageResource(currentItem.photo == null ? "" : currentItem.photo)

Comment: still `(currentItem.photo == null ? "" : currentItem.photo)` is red

Comment: can I have static replacement for this image? if has value show if not use static image

Comment: @mafortis check the answer for how to use `glide` to load the images

Comment: Thank you, I will test that

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work, this part was red `isBlankOrNull(currentItem.photo) ? 0 : currentItem.photo`

Answer (score 0):

Just set image when you are getting it in response i.e. its value is not empty or null.Also you need to use any library to set image to imageview for example You can use Square's [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) and can update your code as below

```
 if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(currentItem.photo))
     Picasso
     .get()
     .load(currentItem.photo)
     .into(holder.imageView)
```

Comment: thanks but I'm using `Glide` not `Picasso`

Comment: Then you can use glide to perform same action. This will resolve your problem.