# How Do I Continuously Update The GUI Using An Asynchronous Thread?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm learning C# and am trying to make a simple application that continuously updates a listview (as new information comes in).

Naturally, I assumed that I could create an async thread to run in perpetuity that would continuously update the listview.

I was able to do this conceptually by creating a threaded function and running it (shown here https://replit.com/@JacksonEnnis4/Def#main.cs).

I tried duplicating this methodology in Xamarin for Android, and got an error that the GUI could only be updated on the "Main Thread".

I saw some people mentioning using RunOnUiThread and a Runnable to succeed in asynchronously updating the UI ([android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161951/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi)), however when I try to implement a C# version of the solution, I get the error

**Line 54**
**"There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'handler' of Runnable.Runnable(Action)"**

I assume that I've missed something, or I have some sort of fundamental misunderstanding of how you would want to update the ui continuously. If anyone could help me, it would mean the world.

Thanks!

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;
using Java.Lang;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Organized_Chaos
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {

        private ArrayAdapter adapter;
        private ListView listView;
        private List<string> testData;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            ObservableCollection<string> person;

            //This basically just loads in the TEST data
            testData = new List<string>();
            testData.Add("Task 1");
            testData.Add("Task 2");
            testData.Add("Task 25");
            testData.Add("Task 26");

            //Creates an adapter for the data
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, testData);
            listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.taskListView);
            //Sets the adapter to the listview
            listView.SetAdapter(adapter);

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => SlowMethod());

        }

        [System.Obsolete]
        private void SlowMethod()
        {
            int counter = 0;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            testData[0] = counter.ToString();
            counter += 1;
            RunOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    //Do stuffs
                }
            });

        }




        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to understand you question? what is your requirement? Pls check this link may help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LY4ATA8Bgw

Comment: Thank you, I see that the way I worded it was vague. I've updated accordingly!